# spacing issues with fonts and size

Tags: fonts, fontsize

I am switching the font as well as the size in a sentence, and I am also using anyfontsize to give me a few more options to make text look nicer. Here is the code:

```
One\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\normalfont % this is required for the change to take effect
{\fontsize{8}{9.6}\selectfont apple}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\rmdefault}
\normalfont among five\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\normalfont % this is required for the change to take effect
{\fontsize{8}{9.6}\selectfont oranges}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\rmdefault}
\normalfont % this is required for the change to take effect
.
```

and it looks like this:

[image]

as you can see the space between "apple" and "among", "oranges" and "." is not consistent with the others, any idea why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have number of spurious spaces (see [What is the use of percent signs (`%`) at the end of lines?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453/5764)) that is causing the problem:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\fontchange}[1]{\textsf{\footnotesize #1}}
\begin{document}

One\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\normalfont % this is required for the change to take effect
{\fontsize{8}{9.6}\selectfont apple}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\rmdefault}% <------ Spurious space
\normalfont among five\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\normalfont % this is required for the change to take effect
{\fontsize{8}{9.6}\selectfont oranges}% %  <------ Spurious space
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\rmdefault}% <------ Spurious space
\normalfont % this is required for the change to take effect
.

One \fontchange{apple} among five \fontchange{oranges}.

\end{document}
```

The alternative (better) option is to [define a macro](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29840/5764) that does the font changes uniformly. It'll also make your code more readable.

Comment: There is no reason for redefining `\familydefault` and issuing `\normalfont`.

Answer (score 3):

The whole font-scaling thing becomes a non-issue if you can switch to either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX:

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec} 
\setmainfont{XITS} % a Times Roman clone
\setsansfont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Helvetica Neue}
\begin{document}
One \textsf{apple} among five \textsf{oranges}.
\end{document}
```

In the present case, `Scale=MathLowercase` seems to be appropriate. For other situations, `Scale=MathUppercase` may be called for. For very special situations, you can also set `Scale=<number>` directly; here, `<number>` should be a positive scalar, generally in the vicinity of 1.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be redefining `\familydefault` to begin with. Also issuing `\normalfont` is not needed.

Just issue `\sffamily` (which implicitly also does `\selectfont`) in a group:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{helvet}

\begin{document}

One {\fontsize{8}{9.6}\sffamily apple} among five
{\fontsize{8}{9.6}\sffamily oranges}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

This is what you get without the `\fontsize` declaration and with the handier `\textsf` command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{helvet}

\begin{document}

One \textsf{apple} among five \textsf{oranges}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Oh, the sans serif words are too big! Yes, they are, but there's a simple way to make them smaller without doing complicated manoeuvers: passing the `scaled=...` option to `helvet`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[scaled=.8]{helvet}

\begin{document}

One \textsf{apple} among five \textsf{oranges}.

\end{document}
```

[image]