# Is there a semantic definition command?

Tags: macros, semantics

Every time I want to emphasize a definition word in a paragraph I need to explicitly state the formatting with `\mathbf{<word(s)>}`. But I'd like to use a semantic command like `\def{<word(s)>}`. Is there a built-in command for this or do I have to define a macro. And if how would I do that?

Comment: Add `\newcommand{\defn}{\textbf}` to your preamble and then use `\defn{<word(s)>}`. Definitely not `\mathbf` and absolutely not `\def`.

Comment: OK, thanks. Can I use `\definition` or would it clash with something?

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29840/consistent-typography

Comment: @implicit_knowledge: I am not sure, but `\definition` might clash with a macro from another package you use in addition. I suggest `\newcommand{\SemDef}{\textbf}` or something similar, in order to prevent clashes