# I want to change the font in math mode for only one letter in an equation

Tags: fonts, math-mode

Some has suggested this is a duplicate question, but I do not think so, because I haven't been able to do it by reading the other posts.
I have something like

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\begin{chapter}
\[
w_1 = ax + b
\]
\end{document}
```

The letter w in the equation appears in common math mode. I want it to appear in eulervm font. I remark: only the w must appear in eulervm font. How to do it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Do you want *all* `w` in math mode to be in the Euler font or just that one?

Comment: Actually, I need a few of them. In a whole section. But I don't want to change the default w in math mode, because I also need it.

Comment: What is the default *math* font supposed to be: Computer Modern or Times?

Comment: I assume it is Times. That's what I think.

Comment: You shouldn't be using `times`, but `mathptmx`, or the math symbols will be in the (non compatible) Computer Modern font. However, the Euler w is quite similar to the Times w, so your choice doesn't seem to be good.

Comment: If `w` has specific meaning, you should [define a macro to be consistent](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29840/5764).

Comment: As an answer to @egreg, what do I have to do then to use mathptmx? And actually, I think the w in euler has a special typography that the normal mode does not have.

Comment: As a comment to @Werner, can you please explain? What do you mean by special meaning?

Comment: @JDavidEC: If `w` represents (say) a vector and you want to denote vectors using a different font. Or, if `w` represents (say) some "wacky constant", you may want to be consistent in its representation.

Comment: @Werner **w** represents a word. And I want to do it this way, because I lready use a **w** for a constant, and **\mathbb{w}** for a vector.

Comment: @JDavidEC: So make sure all words are formatted similarly inside math by defining a macro `\word` that formats its argument accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to work. But it might be the worse way (better wait for a pro answer), I don't really know what I'm doing.

You might want to look at [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14386/21930).

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\DeclareSymbolFont{euletters}       {U}{zeur}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{euletters}{bold}     {U}{zeur}{b}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol\eulerw{\mathalpha}{euletters}{`\w}

\def\enableeulerw
  {\edef\disableeulerw{\mathcode`w=\the\mathcode`\w}\mathcode`\w="8000 }
\def\disableeulerw{}
\begingroup\lccode`~=`w\lowercase{\endgroup\let~}\eulerw


\begin{document}

\section{Foo}
\[
  w_1 = ax + b
\]
\section{Bar}
\enableeulerw
\[
  w_1 = ax + b
\]
\disableeulerw
\section{Baz}
\[
  w_1 = ax + b
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe ``\begingroup\lccode`~=`w\lowercase{\endgroup\let~}\eulerw`` is a bit better than that horrible code with `\detokenize`.

Comment: @egreg, you suggest to replace only the line with \detokenize ?

Comment: @egreg I was amazed with the good looking of `\expandafterw` that I didn't think of that :)

Answer (score 5):

The package `times` has been obsolete for several years; with it the math will still be typeset with Computer Modern that horribly clashes with Times New Roman.

Either use `mathptmx` or, much better, `newtxtext` and `newtxmath`.

However, it turns out that the Euler “w” is not very distinct from the Times italic ”w”, so perhaps you can use the bold version of the Euler letter.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
% for Times in text and math
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
% or the following
%\usepackage{mathptmx}

\DeclareSymbolFont{eulerletters}{U}{zeur}{b}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\eulw}{\mathord}{eulerletters}{`w}

\begin{document}
\[
\eulw_1 = ax + b - w
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

This is how it would be with a medium Euler “w”, obtained by changing the code above in

```
\DeclareSymbolFont{eulerletters}{U}{zeur}{m}{n}
```

[image]

My opinion is that in both cases your readers will not appreciate the distinction.

Maybe using `\mathsf{w}` would be a better choice

```
\[
\mathsf{w}_1 = ax + b - w
\]
```

would produce

[image]

Comment: your solution for the **w** works perfect too !! Thank you so much. But the packages for the fonts changes few things (like \hat{R}, for example).

Comment: @JDavidEC It changes things, because it uses Times for math.