# how to fit algorithm to line width in latex

Tags: width, algorithm2e

the following algorithm exceeded the width of the column:

```
\begin{algorithm}[!htb]
\caption{........}
\label{alg:BuildMG} 
%\algsetup{linenosize=\small}

\scriptsize
\DontPrintSemicolon

\SetKwInOut{Input}{input}\SetKwInOut{Output}{output}
\Input{$Path, CV\_LOAD\_IMAGE\_COLOR$\tcc*[f] { ......}\\} 
\Output{$Array~of~Roots$ \tcc*[f] { .........}\\}

\Begin{
    \nl $InvestigateDirSubDir(Path)$\\
    \nl\ForEach{$file$  \tcc*[f] { ............}\\}{
        \nl\If{$Matobject.data$}{       
             \nl $Increment~~NumberOfImages$ \\
             \nl $cvtColor(-,-,CV\_BGR2GRAY)$\\
             \nl $getHeightWidth()$\\            
             \nl $HeadDLL = buildAgrid(height, width)$\\
             \nl $Previous=arrayOfRoots[NumberOfImages\%NumberOfGroups].east$
             \nl $arrayOfRoots[NumberOfImages\%NumberOfGroups].east=HeadDLL$\\          
             \nl $TailDLL = getLastgrid(HeadDLL)$\\
             \nl $TailDLL->south = Previous$\\           
             }           
        }
    }


\end{algorithm}
```

and the result was as in the following image :

[image]

Comment: An [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) would be very helpful here, especially since you've tagged three algorithm-related packages. I assume the width problem is partially due to this being a two-column document?

Comment: You really really shouldn't use `$ ... $` for italicised text, `$ ... $` is for mathematics and so letters are treated as variables and spaced as such. So `Of` within `$ ... $` is not treated as the word "Of" but some variable *O* multiplied by some variable *f*, which is why you have that horrible spacing between *O* and *f* in *arrayOfRoots* (to give one example). This spacing is horrible within an italicised word, but quite right if these are mathematical variables being multiplied

Comment: just using `\mathit{...} for the "words" will decrease the horizontal space required.  this may be enough so that the lines will fit the available width.

Comment: @Au101 thank u so much for your answer, its working :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your algorithm variables there is not much you can do other than:

- shortening the variables names (while still maintaining readability):
  Perhaps use `ImageNum` and `GroupNum` instead of `NumberOfImages` and `NumberOfGroups`.
- reducing the horizontal indentation for nested structures:
  Use `\SetInd` to reduce the space around the `v`ertical `lines`.

The line-breaking is as expected, since there is no hyphenation pattern specified for the "words" used in your algorithm. Moreover, setting everything inside math mode allows break-points only to occur at specific locations, like binary operators (`+`, say) or relations (`=`, say).

The below example attempts to highlight both the above measures, as well as suggest a more appropriate formatting for the components of your algorithm. To that end, it defines

- `\var{<variable>}` to set a `<variable>`;
- `\proc{<procedure>}{<arguments>}` to set a `<procedure>` with possible `<arguments>`; and
- `\prop{<property>}` to set a `<property>` associated with a variable:

[Defining macros to take care of the formatting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/29846/5764) allows you to easily change this in the future.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}

\newcommand{\var}{\texttt}
\newcommand{\proc}[2]{\textsl{#1}(#2)}
\newcommand{\prop}{\textit}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
  \caption{Building MedGraph}

  \footnotesize
  \DontPrintSemicolon

  \SetKwInOut{Input}{input}\SetKwInOut{Output}{output}
  \Input{\var{Path}, \var{CV\_LOAD\_IMAGE\_COLOR} \tcc*[f] {Path to the directory and subdirectories that contain images}}
  \Output{Array of roots \tcc*[f] {The indexing structure}}

  \Begin{
    \nl \proc{InvestigateDirSubDir}{\var{Path}}\;
    \tcc*[f] { Mat object is used as a handler for a file} \\[-\baselineskip]
    \nl\ForEach{\var{file}}{
      \nl\If{\var{Matobject.data}}{       
        \nl Increment \var{ImageNum}\;
        \nl \proc{cvtColor}{\var{-},\var{-},\var{CV\_BGR2GRAY)}}\;
        \nl \proc{getHeightWidth}{}\;
        \nl $\var{HeadDLL} = \proc{buildAgrid}{\var{height}, \var{width}}$\;
        \nl $\var{Previous} = \var{arrayOfRoots}[\var{ImageNum\%GroupNum}].\prop{east}$\;
        \nl $\var{arrayOfRoots}[\var{ImageNum\%GroupNum}].\prop{east} = \var{HeadDLL}$\;
        \nl $\var{TailDLL} = \proc{getLastgrid}{\var{HeadDLL}}$\;
        \nl $\var{TailDLL}.\prop{south} = \var{Previous}$\;
      }
    }
  }
\end{algorithm}

%\SetInd{<before rule space>}{<after rule space>}
%\SetInd{0.5em}{1em}% Default
\SetInd{0.5em}{0.5em}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
  \caption{Building MedGraph}

  \footnotesize
  \DontPrintSemicolon

  \SetKwInOut{Input}{input}\SetKwInOut{Output}{output}
  \Input{\var{Path}, \var{CV\_LOAD\_IMAGE\_COLOR} \tcc*[f] {Path to the directory and subdirectories that contain images}}
  \Output{Array of roots \tcc*[f] {The indexing structure}}

  \Begin{
    \nl \proc{InvestigateDirSubDir}{\var{Path}}\;
    \tcc*[f] { Mat object is used as a handler for a file} \\[-\baselineskip]
    \nl\ForEach{\var{file}}{
      \nl\If{\var{Matobject.data}}{       
        \nl Increment \var{ImageNum}\;
        \nl \proc{cvtColor}{\var{-},\var{-},\var{CV\_BGR2GRAY)}}\;
        \nl \proc{getHeightWidth}{}\;
        \nl $\var{HeadDLL} = \proc{buildAgrid}{\var{height}, \var{width}}$\;
        \nl $\var{Previous} = \var{arrayOfRoots}[\var{ImageNum\%GroupNum}].\prop{east}$\;
        \nl $\var{arrayOfRoots}[\var{ImageNum\%GroupNum}].\prop{east} = \var{HeadDLL}$\;
        \nl $\var{TailDLL} = \proc{getLastgrid}{\var{HeadDLL}}$\;
        \nl $\var{TailDLL}.\prop{south} = \var{Previous}$\;
      }
    }
  }
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

`\SetInd{<before rule space>}{<after rule space>}` was used to adjust the spacing around the `v`ertical `rules` in the second algorithm.

<sub>Another option would be to reduce the font size even more, but that's a bit ridiculous. Finally, you can set the entire algorithm in a box and shrink it to fit the `\linewidth`. However, that's equivalently non-beautiful.</sub>