# Positioning a picture in place of a letter

Tags: graphics

I wonder if you can place a picture (JPG or PDF) within a text as in the image below:

[image]

Comment: You should just try it! Use `...it is convenient to define $\includegraphics[height=.7\baselineskip]{img} = ..$ ...` The image will rest on the baseline and be scaled to have a height that shouldn't affect the inter-line spacing. Movements up/down are also possible.

Comment: As long as you don't use a `\begin{figure}...\end{figure}` approach this should work (with the correct scaling and baseline, as Werner already noted)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Images are treated just like characters in LaTeX, so insert it using `\includegraphics` as-is:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\mysymbol}{%
  \raisebox{-.2\baselineskip}{% ...lower image slightly
    \includegraphics[height=.8\baselineskip]{example-image}}}

\begin{document}

In Theorem~2.4 we show that, for any given $x_0 \in \mathcal{H} \setminus A^{-1}(0)$, 
and $\theta > 0$, there exists a unique strong (locally Lipschitz in time) global solution
$t \mapsto (x(t), \lambda(t))$ of~\mbox{(4)} which satisfies the Cauchy data $x(0) = x_0$.
It is convenient to define 
$\mysymbol = \{(\omega,\eta,\zeta) : \psi_{\Lambda,\beta,h}(\omega,\eta,\zeta) = 0, \mathrm{hold(2,a),(2.b)}\}$.

\end{document}
```

Note that I defined a macro for the "symbol" you want to use. This would be typical if you want to re-use the notation throughout your document; [it promotes consistency](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/29846/5764).

Comment: Note that the use of `\baselineskip` might not function as expected inside a `tabular`. However, for the means of the post and usage in general, it should suffice.

Answer (score 2):

There is a `\vcenter` which works in `mathmode`. It will automatically take care of the height and center the picture on the level of the `minus` sign. So, your `\newcommand` can look like this:

```
\newcommand{\mysymbol}{%
  \vcenter{\hbox{\includegraphics[height=2\baselineskip]{example-image}}
  }
}
```

See an example below with a slightly bigger picture to see how it works.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\mysymbol}{%
  \vcenter{\hbox{\includegraphics[height=2\baselineskip]{example-image}}
  }
}

\begin{document}

In Theorem~2.4 we show that, for any given $x_0 \in \mathcal{H} \setminus A^{-1}(0)$, 
and $\theta > 0$, there exists a unique strong (locally Lipschitz in time) global solution
$t \mapsto (x(t), \lambda(t))$ of~\mbox{(4)} which satisfies the Cauchy data $x(0) = x_0$.
It is convenient to define 
$\mysymbol = \{(\omega,\eta,\zeta) : \psi_{\Lambda,\beta,h}(\omega,\eta,\zeta) = 0, \mathrm{hold(2,a),(2.b)}\}$.
\\
In Theorem~2.4 we show that, for any given $x_0 \in \mathcal{H} \setminus A^{-1}(0)$, 
and $\theta > 0$, there exists a unique strong (locally Lipschitz in time) global solution
$t \mapsto (x(t), \lambda(t))$ of~\mbox{(4)} which satisfies the Cauchy data $x(0) = x_0$.
It is convenient to define 
$\mysymbol = \{(\omega,\eta,\zeta) : \psi_{\Lambda,\beta,h}(\omega,\eta,\zeta) = 0, \mathrm{hold(2,a),(2.b)}\}$.

\end{document}
```

[image]