# Combination spacing

Tags: math-mode, spacing

I need to show the multiplication of two combinations.

Code:

```
$_4\rm C_2\times_7\rm C_2$
```

Output:

[image: output]

As you can see, the spacing is strange and hard to read (the '7' is far to the left). How can I fix this? I will be needing to do this very frequently.

Comment: The spacing around the `7` is incorrect as you're setting it as a subscript to `\times`.

Comment: It's always better to set a subscript *to* something.  If there's really "nothing", i.e., you're dealing with a prescript, then use `{}` as the token "something".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need it frequently, then you need to create a macro for it. It'll make life easier and more [consistent](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/29846/5764)!

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\comb}[2]{{}_{#1}\mathrm{C}_{#2}}

\begin{document}

$\comb{4}{2} \times \comb{7}{2} = \binom{4}{2} \times \binom{7}{2}$

\end{document}
```