# Make < behave like \langle

Tags: math-mode, spacing, symbols

In a document I am writing I have to make heavy use of the notation M with the angle-brackets, so I'm using `$M\langle x \rangle$`, I would like to use instead `$M<x>$`as it is a lot more readable (and faster to type!) but it leaves a nasty space around the symbol. Is there a way to change the behaviour of the symbols `<` and `>` in math mode to behave as `\langle`and `rangle`?

Thank you

Comment: In cases like this, I think it's better to define a logical macro to handle the setting (promoting [consistency](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29840/5764)), say, `\newcommand{\domain}[1]{M\langle #1\rangle}`. Using `\domain{x}` seems pretty readable to me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The LaTeX kernel (`fontmath.ltx`) defines the symbols the following way:

```
\DeclareMathDelimiter{<}{\mathopen}{symbols}{"68}{largesymbols}{"0A}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{>}{\mathclose}{symbols}{"69}{largesymbols}{"0B}
...
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\rangle}
   {\mathclose}{symbols}{"69}{largesymbols}{"0B}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\langle}
   {\mathopen}{symbols}{"68}{largesymbols}{"0A}
```

Thus, it is possible to define `<` and `>` the same way as `\langle` and `\rangle`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareMathDelimiter{<}{\mathopen}{symbols}{"68}{largesymbols}{"0A}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{>}{\mathclose}{symbols}{"69}{largesymbols}{"0B}

\begin{document}
$M< x >$
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

The next example safes the less and greater signs in macros `\less` and `\greater` for the case they are needed:

```
\documentclass{article}

\mathchardef\less=\mathcode`<
\mathchardef\greater=\mathcode`>

\DeclareMathDelimiter{<}{\mathopen}{symbols}{"68}{largesymbols}{"0A}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{>}{\mathclose}{symbols}{"69}{largesymbols}{"0B}

\begin{document}
$1 \greater 0 \less M< x >$
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result with less and greater signs]

Other math fonts may have different symbol encodings. Example for `MnSymbol`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}

\mathchardef\less=\mathcode`<
\mathchardef\greater=\mathcode`>

\DeclareMathDelimiter{<}{\mathopen}{largesymbols}{'140}{largesymbols}{'140}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{>}{\mathclose}{largesymbols}{'145}{largesymbols}{'145}

\begin{document}
$1 \greater 0 \less M< x >$
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result MnSymbol]

A more automatic solution, which assumes that `\langle` and `\rangle` are defined by LaTeX's `\DeclareMathDelimiter` with a definition text as `\delimiter"` followed by 7 hexadecimal digits. Then the values for the math category code for the redefined `<` and `>` can be extracted from the definition of `\langle` and `\rangle`. Packages like `MnSymbol`, `mathabx`, `txfonts` works then out of the box (if they are loaded *before*).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{txfonts}

\mathchardef\less=\mathcode`<
\mathchardef\greater=\mathcode`>

\def\tmp{\delimiter"}
\edef\tmp{\meaning\tmp}
\expandafter\def\expandafter\ScanDelimiterDefinition\tmp#1#2#3#4#5\relax#6{%
  \mathcode`#6="#1#2#3#4\relax
}
\expandafter\ScanDelimiterDefinition\meaning\langle\relax<
\expandafter\ScanDelimiterDefinition\meaning\rangle\relax>

\begin{document}
$1 \greater 0 \less M< x >$
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result txfonts]

Comment: I don't understand: It seems like the LaTeX kernel defines `<` [`>`] to be exactly the same as `\langle` [`\rangle`], yet one still has to redefine it?

Comment: @Werner the normal symbols are different: `<` and `>` use family `operators` and `\langle` and `\rangle` use family `symbols`. But in the case of a large delimiters (e.g. `\left...\right...`), the symbols are mapped to the same math font `largesymbols` and `<` and `\langle`, and `>` and `\rangle` are the same symbols, mapped to the same slots. `<` and `>` are relational operators, but if they are used as delimiters they become `\langle` and `\rangle`.

Answer (score 5):

Similar to Heiko's, but with less cryptic code: the required `\mathcode` can be obtained by dividing (with truncation) the `\delcode`:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{newtxmath}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \mathchardef\lt=\mathcode`<
  \mathchardef\gt=\mathcode`>
  \count255=\delcode`< \divide\count255 "1000
  \mathcode`<=\count255
  \count255=\delcode`> \divide\count255 "1000
  \mathcode`>=\count255
}

\begin{document}
$1 \gt 0 \lt M<x>$

$\displaystyle\left<\frac{a}{b}\right>$

$<\bigl<\Bigl<\biggl<\Biggl<\Biggr>\biggr>\Bigr>\bigr>>$
\end{document}
```

This should be independent of the math font package.

[image]

On the other hand, you might use `mathtools` and `\DeclarePairedDelimiter`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
%\usepackage{newtxmath}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\avg}{\langle}{\rangle}


\begin{document}
$1 < 0 < M\avg{x}$

$\displaystyle\avg*{\frac{a}{b}}$

$\avg{\avg[\big]{\avg[\Big]{\avg[\bigg]{\avg[\Bigg]x}}}}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 for recommending using `\DeclarePairedDelimiter`, which I think is the *real* solution.