# includegraphics with negative bottom margin

Tags: graphics, vertical-alignment

i've got some graphic included within the text like so:

`Sounds scary \includegraphics[width=1.2em]{images/zwinker.png}`

this is the output:

[image]

but i'd like this output instead (graphic moved a bit down to fit nicer in the flow of the text):

[image]

how can i achieve this?

Comment: You could manually apply a `\raisebox` to the `\includegraphics` or you could `\clipbox` to remove the empty bottom of the image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple `\raisebox{0.3\height}` will do:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} 

\begin{document}

Sounds scary \raisebox{-0.3\height}{\includegraphics[scale = 0.08]{zwinkern}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

By default, images are set on the baseline of the current line. You can `c`enter this `v`ertically by using [`adjustbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox)'s `valign=c` option:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\newcommand{\scarysymbol}[1][]{\includegraphics[width=1.2em,valign=c,#1]{example-image}}

\begin{document}

Something scary \includegraphics[width=1.2em]{example-image}.

Something scary \includegraphics[width=1.2em,valign=c]{example-image}.

Something scary \scarysymbol.

\end{document}
```

Alternatively, you can "raise" the image into position via `\raisebox{<value>}{<stuff>}`, where `<value>` can be a negative dimension and `<stuff>` is your `\includegraphics`. However, letting `adjustbox` sort this out is far simpler.

For [consistency](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29840/5764), store your scary symbol in a macro (say) `\scarysymbol`.