# How do I bold the 'title' of a paragraph?

Tags: sectioning

I would like to describe several points in several paragraphs. I want to give 'title' for each point at the beginning of the paragraph like this:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! How about `\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\paragraph{This is}\hspace*{-1em} some important stuff that begins with ``this is''. ``This
is'' simply the argument of a \verb|\paragraph|.
\end{document}`?

Answer (score 2):

You want to list the `description` of things? Use the `description` environment.

```
\documentclass[preview, border={1cm 1cm 1cm 1cm}]{standalone}

\begin{document}

Aliquam sem magna, varius vel justo sit amet, vulputate faucibus lorem. Sed
lacinia lectus odio, in interdum justo viverra nec. In a aliquam quam.
Suspendisse scelerisque est quis facilisis vulputate. Fusce facilisis turpis
tortor, nec ornare est vehicula in. Suspendisse aliquam eros sollicitudin mauris
varius facilisis:

\begin{description}
  \item[Lorem ipsum] dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam in nunc
    sed mi mollis sodales. Suspendisse lobortis venenatis convallis. Maecenas
    laoreet pretium pulvinar.

  \item[Curabitur pellentesque] lacus felis, vitae volutpat augue posuere sit amet.
    Suspendisse et diam at lorem tristique pulvinar sed eget turpis. Aliquam
    rutrum consectetur felis.

  \item[Aliquam ac faucibus risus] proin sodales sagittis nulla id lacinia. Fusce quis
    libero magna. Mauris auctor neque lectus, in porta ligula facilisis a. Donec
    consectetur erat neque, nec auctor felis viverra id. Praesent quis nulla
    pulvinar, ultricies mi sit amet, feugiat risus. Quisque imperdiet dapibus arcu
    vitae pretium.

  \item[Donec non augue] leo nam pharetra auctor ex, viverra sagittis justo.
    Nulla pharetra ligula sit amet posuere interdum. Proin sollicitudin ornare
    tempus. Ut interdum purus aliquet, vestibulum orci a, viverra arcu. Maecenas
    finibus ligula
\end{description}

Pellentesque augue sem, sodales vitae pretium in, finibus at lacus. Sed vel
augue interdum, dictum ligula et, egestas libero. Nullam vitae nulla laoreet,
tincidunt elit et, pretium enim. Vestibulum quis ipsum molestie, varius elit eu,
venenatis risus. Aliquam auctor metus magna, ac ultrices arcu faucibus quis. Nam
dictum, quam sit amet egestas scelerisque, ipsum lorem faucibus sem, eu mattis
nisi ex nec nunc.

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If you don't like the indentation, set `[leftmargin=0pt]` with the `enumitem` package.

```
\documentclass[preview, border={1cm 1cm 1cm 1cm}]{standalone}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

Aliquam sem magna, varius vel justo sit amet, vulputate faucibus lorem. Sed
lacinia lectus odio, in interdum justo viverra nec. In a aliquam quam.
Suspendisse scelerisque est quis facilisis vulputate. Fusce facilisis turpis
tortor, nec ornare est vehicula in. Suspendisse aliquam eros sollicitudin mauris
varius facilisis:

\begin{description}[leftmargin=0pt]
  \item[Lorem ipsum] dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam in nunc
    sed mi mollis sodales. Suspendisse lobortis venenatis convallis. Maecenas
    laoreet pretium pulvinar.

  \item[Curabitur pellentesque] lacus felis, vitae volutpat augue posuere sit amet.
    Suspendisse et diam at lorem tristique pulvinar sed eget turpis. Aliquam
    rutrum consectetur felis.

  \item[Aliquam ac faucibus risus] proin sodales sagittis nulla id lacinia. Fusce quis
    libero magna. Mauris auctor neque lectus, in porta ligula facilisis a. Donec
    consectetur erat neque, nec auctor felis viverra id. Praesent quis nulla
    pulvinar, ultricies mi sit amet, feugiat risus. Quisque imperdiet dapibus arcu
    vitae pretium.

  \item[Donec non augue] leo nam pharetra auctor ex, viverra sagittis justo.
    Nulla pharetra ligula sit amet posuere interdum. Proin sollicitudin ornare
    tempus. Ut interdum purus aliquet, vestibulum orci a, viverra arcu. Maecenas
    finibus ligula
\end{description}

Pellentesque augue sem, sodales vitae pretium in, finibus at lacus. Sed vel
augue interdum, dictum ligula et, egestas libero. Nullam vitae nulla laoreet,
tincidunt elit et, pretium enim. Vestibulum quis ipsum molestie, varius elit eu,
venenatis risus. Aliquam auctor metus magna, ac ultrices arcu faucibus quis. Nam
dictum, quam sit amet egestas scelerisque, ipsum lorem faucibus sem, eu mattis
nisi ex nec nunc.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `description` is a nice way of solving this.

Answer (score 1):

[Define a macro](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/29846/5764) the would highlight the first content of a given paragraph. Something like `\keyword`, say:

```
\newcommand{\keyword}{\textbf}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\keyword}{\textbf}

\begin{document}

\keyword{Grammar-based models} rely on a pre-defined grammar for 
generating a particular modality. They start by detecting
high level concepts from the source modality, such as objects
in images and actions from videos. These detections are then 
incorporated together with a generation procedure based on
a pre-defined grammar to result in a target modality.

\end{document}
```