# How to change a single factor font inside the equation?

Tags: math-mode, fonts, amsmath

I have two equations with the same letter "T" and I would like to change one of then to not give the impression that are the same. One of them represents temperature(this one I want to change), by the way.

Comment: You should [define names for repeated items](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29840/5764), like `\newcommand{\Temp}{T}`, which allows some contextual reference within the equation. And yes, then you can use `\newcommand{otherT}{\mathsf{T}}`, or something like that.

Comment: You could also put any font command you like inside the `\text` command from `amsmath`, and optionally wrap it in `\mathord`.