# Highlighting only the bottom half of a word

Tags: tcolorbox, highlighting, underline, colorbox

I would like to define a command for highlighting in the following style.
[image]
Some people do this on paper and I would like to mimic that on a particular document. How could I achieve this? I thought of using the package `tcolorbox`, but I am at a loss as to how to approach it using the package and as it is simple perhaps it could be done without using this package.  I would like the command to receive as arguments the colour of the highlighting and the content to be highlighted. I would like this to work with `XeLaTeX`.

**EDIT:** I've tested @abcdefg's solution and the following problem arose.
[image]
How can I make the rectangle be always at the same level? It would be nice if it could begin a little bellow the line base and advance up to the middle height of the characters. It would also be nice if the behaviour of the macro were favorable to line breaks.

Comment: Take a look at either the `soul` or `ulem` package. If LuaLaTeX was an option, `lua-ul` would be interesting as well.

Comment: Should the highlight be breakable across lines?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here I use `\ooalign` to get the rule, and a tokencycle to achieve line breaking (however, hyphenation is lost, which may require `sloppypar` to remedy, in some cases, such as the MWE).

EDITED to use `\discretionary` in the `\Spacedirective`, to avoid hanging spaces when linebreaking.

REEDITED to add some glue to assist with justification.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,tokcycle}
\newlength\replength
\newcommand\ruleht{-1.5pt}% ELEVATION OF RULE
\newcommand\rulewidth{4pt}% THICKNESS OF RULE
\def\rulecolor{purple!30}% COLOR OF RULE
\newcommand\sphl[1]{\sbox0{#1}\ooalign{\makebox[0pt][l]{%
  \smash{\color{\rulecolor}\rule[\ruleht]{\wd0}{\rulewidth}}}\cr#1}}
\newcommand\myul[2]{%
  \resettokcycle
  \Characterdirective{\addcytoks{\nobreak\hspace{0pt minus.6pt}%
    \sphl{##1}}}%
  \Spacedirective{\addcytoks{\nobreak\hspace{0pt minus .6pt}%
    \discretionary{}{}{\sphl{\ }}}}%
  \cytoks{}%
  \def\rulecolor{#1}%
  \tokcyclexpress{#2}%
  \the\cytoks%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{sloppypar}
Now I will try my special underlining \myul{purple!25}{%
This is a test, we will
  see if word wrapping occurs automatically or not
This is a test, we will
  see if word wrapping occurs automatically or not
This is a test, we will
  see if word wrapping occurs automatically or not
This is a test, we will
  see if word wrapping occurs automatically or not
This is a test, we will
  see if word wrapping occurs automatically or not
This is a test, we will
  see if word wrapping occurs automatically or not} back to normal text.
\end{sloppypar}

\noindent\hrulefill
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, @Steven B. Segletes! Thank you for your answer. What did you mean by "line breaks will end on an explicit space". I've checked the rule breaks in this case:  `The rule is \myul{not\ whole}.` It results as  `The rule is \myul{not} \myul{whole}.`

Comment: @Tera What I meant was, with my original answer, there would be an underlined empty space hanging off the right end of the line break.  Now, as you see, with the `\hrulefill` added to provide a comparison to the textwidth, the underlined text goes flush up to each (left and right) margins.

Comment: @Tera Put another way, at linebreaks, the space should be "eaten", showing neither at the prior line-end nor the new line-start.  It was not eaten with the original implementation...with `\discretionary`, it is now properly eaten at line breaks.

Comment: Your explanation is very clear! I had interpreted your sentence way wrongly.

Comment: your solutions works perfectly! I could not however adjust it to produce a command of the type `\myul{<color>}{<content to be highlighted>}`. I tried changing  the definitions of  `\sphl` and  `\myul `  to make them receive two arguments but must've made some mistake for the content ended up appearing repeatedly on the pdf.  What is the proper way to make `\myul ` receive such two arguments without interfering in the `tokcycle` mechanism?

Comment: @Tera Try this change to the macro: `\newcommand\myul[2]{%
  \resettokcycle
  \Characterdirective{\addcytoks{\sphl{##1}}}%
  \Spacedirective{\addcytoks{\discretionary{}{}{\sphl{\ }}}}%
  \cytoks{}%
  \def\rulecolor{#1}%
  \tokcyclexpress{#2}%
  \the\cytoks%
}`

Comment: @Tera I added a further edit, to add some negative glue, which will assist with justification for extended underlining passages.

Answer (score 7):

`tcolorbox` is arguably one of the most powerful option if you seek extensions later on.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tcbset{twilight/.style={enhanced,hbox,colback=white,
underlay={\begin{tcbclipinterior}
\fill[#1] let \p1=($(interior.north)-(interior.south)$) in
([yshift={0.5*\y1}]interior.south west) rectangle 
(interior.south east);
\end{tcbclipinterior}}},twilight/.default=purple!50,
tight/.style={on
line,boxsep=0pt,left=#1,right=#1,top=#1,bottom=#1,arc=0pt,boxrule=0pt,colframe=white},
tight/.default=0pt}
\begin{document}

One wishes to highlight
\begin{tcolorbox}[tight,twilight]
this expression
\end{tcolorbox} in a sentence.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In this use case it probably seems better to write a macro; something like `\halful{<text>}`.

Comment: @Werner You mean something like `One wishes to highlight
\tcbox[tight,twilight]{this expression} in a sentence.`? This already works with the current version of the answer, i.e. it is aready taken care of by `tcolorbox` which indeed provides users with a macro version.

Comment: Sure. I'm thinking more along the lines of `\newcommand{\halful}[1][]{\tcbox[tight,twilight,#1]}` (as suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/29846/5764), since it provides context in the macro name).

Comment: @Werner Sure, that works. Note, however, that `tcolorbox` has the `\newtcbox` command (see p. 16 of the manual) for this which comes with some additional advanced options, but also allows you to define a macro along the lines you suggest.

Comment: E.g. `\newtcbox{\halffull}[1][]{tight,twilight,#1}

One wishes to highlight \halffull{this expression} in a sentence.`

Comment: Hi, @abcdefg. Thanks for the answer. I'll edit the question to display an image of a problem that arose.

Comment: Besides, in the spirit of what @Werner draw attention to, how could a set the `\halffull` receive also the name of the colour to be used?

Comment: @Tera This is also already included. `\newtcbox{\halffull}[1][]{tight,twilight,#1,before upper=\strut}

One wishes to highlight \halffull[twilight=blue!50]{this expression} in a 
\halffull{sentence}.`. I added a `\strut` to address the problem in the updated question.

Comment: `\strut` will make the box always begin at the lowest level, won't it? as if there was a phantom "p" or other letter which extends downwards. I'm using the font Libertinus and the "tails" of p's and q's are rather long. This makes this fix look rather awkward. I'm searching the `tcolorbox` package trying to understand how to set the rectangle at a level just above the lowest level.

Comment: Also, is there a way to make `colback` transparent instead of white?, for when the page color is not really white.

Comment: @Tera Yes, this is all possible. However, as this is an evolving question I stop evolving the answer. It isn't too entertaining for me to get the requirements told afterwards, and I also cannot quite understand why Werner's comment is so much highlighted. In short, I write answers to answer questions in their original form, and I am not interested in playing reputation or other games.

Comment: I understand. Perhaps I am to be blamed for not having anticipated some of the issues too be avoided and requirements or not having made them more explicit from the start. Thank you for your answers, they were helpful and I learned from them.