# How do I make geometrical symbols in LATEX?

Tags: symbols

I would like to know how to make geometric symbols denoting lines, line segments, rays, arcs, or circles. This is what they should look like. I have tried symbol searching things like DeTextify, but it can't find symbols that attach to other letters.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to look up a symbol or identify a letter from a math alphabet or other character?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol-or-identify-a-letter-from-a-math-alphabet-or-other-chara)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is a start, using elements from the [Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](//texdoc.net/pkg/comprehensive):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,mathabx}

% For convenience and syntax, define your own commands for each.
% See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/29846/5764
\newcommand{\Line}{\overleftrightarrow}
\newcommand{\Linesegment}{\overline}
\newcommand{\Ray}{\overrightarrow}
\newcommand{\Yar}{\overleftarrow}
\newcommand{\Arc}{\overgroup}
\newcommand{\Circle}{\mathord{\odot}}

\begin{document}

\[
  \Line{AB},
  \Linesegment{AB},
  \Ray{AB},
  \Yar{AB},
  \Arc{AB},
  \Circle A
\]

\end{document}
```

<sub>While [`amsmath`](//ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) is not needed in the example above, it's good to use for other things.</sub>

Comment: what does \mathord do

Comment: @SomeGuy Tells LaTeX that the symbol is an “ordinary” symbol, and not a binary operator, relation, or something else. That affects the spacing of the expression.

Answer (score 8):

The whole list of latex symbols is here: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/comprehensive

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fourier}
\begin{document}
\[
  \overleftrightarrow{AB}, \overline{AB},\overrightarrow{AB},  \widearc{AB}, \wideparen{AB}, \odot A
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]