# how to bold text in cases

Tags: cases, boldmath

I am trying to write a Dirac delta function. I almost have it but would like to bold my "x =x'" text.

Here is my code:

```
\begin{equation}
\delta(\mathbf{x-x^{'}})=\begin{cases}
            1, & \text{$x = x'$}\\
            0, & \text{$x \neq x'$}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
```

I also tried this:

```
\begin{equation}
\delta(\mathbf{x-x^{'}})=\begin{cases}
            1, & \textbf{$x = x'$}\\
            0, & \textbf{$x \neq x'$}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
```

but that gives the same output

Edit:from teddies comments this is the latex code I used to get the result I wanted:

```
\begin{equation}
\delta(\mathbf{x-x'})=\begin{cases}
            1, & \mathbf{ x = x'}\\
            0, & \mathbf{ x \neq x'}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Unrelated, but 1. `x'` not `x^{'}`. 2. No need to have `\text{$...$}`, just write the math.

Comment: As to your question, `\bm` by `\usepackage{bm}` would suit you well.

Answer (score 3):

You haven't indicated whether the bold `x` symbols should be rendered in upright or in slanted/italic lettering. The following code shows how to pursue either variant.

[image]

I wouldn't render the `-` (minus), `'` (prime), `=` (equals), or `\neq` (not equal to) symbols in bold.

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{amsmath}    % for 'cases' environment
\usepackage{bm}         % for '\bm' macdro
\newcommand\bfx{\mathbf{x}} % "upright bold" x
\newcommand\bmx{\bm{x}}     % "italic bold" x

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\delta(\bfx-\bfx')
=\begin{cases}
        1 & \text{if $\bfx=\bfx'$,}\\
        0 & \text{if $\bfx\neq\bfx'$.}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\delta(\bmx-\bmx')
=\begin{cases}
        1 & \text{if $\bmx=\bmx'$,}\\
        0 & \text{if $\bmx\neq\bmx'$.}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Define your own command for vectors.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}

\newcommand{\vect}[1]{\mathbf{#1}} % vector
%\newcommand{\vect}[1]{\bm{#1}} % vector

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\delta(\vect{x}-\vect{x}')=
\begin{cases}
  1, & \vect{x} = \vect{x}' \\
  0, & \vect{x} \neq \vect{x}'
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you switch the comments, so use `\bm` instead of `\mathbf`, you get

[image]

Defining an own command ensures uniformity and has the advantage that you can change the typographic representation of *all* vectors with a single shot.

Comment: ...as suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/29846/5764).