# Checking if a PDF file is open

Tags: pdf, filesystem-access

How do I check if the PDF file produced by LaTeX is currently opened by an application or not?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you please elaborate and clarify a little more?

Comment: I think he means if it is in use, e.g., if you want to write over it.

Comment: i need: if file.pdf is open then close... else acroread file.pdf

Comment: As far as I can tell, this has nothing to do with LaTeX.

Comment: Are you trying to synchronously edit and view the resulting PDF? And you want to close the PDF if you accidentally left it open in Acrobat?

Comment: yes, in command line.

Comment: That is going to be operating system dependent.  I can see implementing it in AppleScript on Mac OS, but it doesn't sound like that's an option for you.

Comment: The answer to your question involves the filesystem; in fact it's not a problem regarding a software ( it's simply misleading to talk about Adobe Reader or something like that ) or the operative system but it's about how the files on disk are organized and what are the feature of the filesystem you are actually using. Considering the filesystem as main topic it's almost impossible to give a generic answer, it's possible to give a specific answer but only if you gives us the names of your filesystem and the name of your operative system.

Comment: @JanHlavacek: It's still on-topic though, it's about "(La)TeX related software and tools like BibTeX, LyX, LaTeX editors, viewers, and converters" ([faq]). When you want to compile, you need to close the document first in some viewers. In order to do so, you need to check if it's open first.

Comment: @RegisdaSilva: Then would you _please_ edit your question?

Answer (score 7):

I assume that your question is related to the fact that PDFLaTeX cannot write to a file if it is open in Acrobat Reader.  The older versions of Acrobat Reader could be closed and reopend with external DDE commands but not versions 9 and X as far as I know.

Acrobat Reader can also not support the new synctex technology, so the best here is [Sumatra PDF](http://blog.kowalczyk.info/software/sumatrapdf/free-pdf-reader.html) for the windows environment. You do not need to close it when compiling your document and it supports the inverse search via synctex. Some of the editors such as [WinEdt](http://www.winedt.com/) on windows supports it directly and the inverse search works very well. [WinShell](http://www.winshell.org/) and [TexStudio](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/) (formerly known as TexMakerX) for windows can be configured to use it with synctex support. Alternatively use one of the editors with buildin viewers with synctex support such as [TexWorks](http://www.tug.org/texworks/), [TexMaker](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/) or TexStudio.

Comment: Danie, i understand. But i use Linux and terminal command.

Comment: @Regis da Silva: Unfortunately I do not know much about Linux. As far a I know is [Evince](http://projects.gnome.org/evince) a lot more friendly and has limited synctex support.

Comment: @Regis da Silva: see also [stackexchange](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2941/how-to-setup-synctex-with-vim-pdflatex-and-an-open-source-pdf-viewer-under-linux)

Comment: TeXworks is available for Linux, too, and is already packaged for most common Linux distributions, like Debian, Ubuntu, Suse, Fedora, ...

Comment: @Regis da Silva: Evince, for example, reloads the document if it is changed. You don't have to close/open anything. Other viewers like Okular probably do the same.

Comment: But in linux, nothing stops you from writing over a pdf file that is open in adobe reader.  As for relaoding an open file on Adobe reader, look at this discussion: http://forums.adobe.com/thread/395299

Comment: How close the file.pdf (if is open) in shell terminal linux?

Comment: There are DDE commands for 9 and X as well, search the internet for [acroviewR10](https://www.google.com/search?q=acroviewR10) or [acroviewR10+DDE](http://www.google.com/search?q=acroviewR10+DDE).

Comment: The problem is not the program creating the PDF (e.g. pdfTeX), but the viewer: Some of these (e.g. Adobe Reader and Foxit 5.x) lock the file so that it can not be written to. The solution for this is simple: Use a PDF viewer that doesn't lock the file, e.g. Sumatra PDF.

Answer (score 4):

Since you mentioned that you're using linux in one of the comments, the standard way to determine if a programme is currently accesing a file is the `lsof` command. Example:

```
user@host:~$ lsof /path/to/filename.pdf
COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF     NODE NAME
okular  3961  user   26r   REG   0,21  5357342 12608996 /path/to/filename.pdf
```

Reading over the comments, you said you wanted to kill that process, here's a one-liner for it.

```
kill $(lsof -Fp /path/to/filename | egrep -o "[0-9]+")
```

Explanation: lsof finds the filename & -Fp option pulls the PID , egrep (grep with extended regex syntax that I'm more comfortable with) grabs only the numbers since it prints pXXXX. This is wrapped in $() and evaluated first, then the kill is run. Thanks to kahen for knowing the command line option for getting the PID

Comment: This can be improved. `lsof` supports setting its output format with the `-F` option. Try this: `touch ./FOO; tail -f ./FOO & /lsof -Fp ./FOO; rm ./FOO` (pay attention to the PID of tail, so you can kill it later and remember to delete ./FOO)

Comment: Cheers. Changes added. I'd never stuck lsof in a one liner before so I just went the lazy solution of awk/grep

Comment: @RegisdaSilva, is this the correct answer? If so it would be helpful for others if you would mark it as such.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using linux, I can tell you that you probably should not need to check if the file is open.

When I compile the `.tex` file (usually with `pdflatex`), I'm also viewing the `.pdf` document with either of these:

- **xpdf**: simply press <kbd>r</kbd> and it will refresh the document.
- **evince**: it refreshes automatically.

Comment: True, in Linux Acrobat doesn't lock the PDF, and you can also press Ctrl+R to refresh.