# Window focus problem during inverse-search from Okular to GVIM

Tags: vim, forward-inverse-search, okular

I have just setup the nice *inverse search* feature, from `okular`, by using the command `gvim --remote-silent +%l %f`  as a custom-editor.

It seems to work perfectly fine except a small bug that has been annoying me for the last many hours:

> Once the `shift+click` is used in `okular`, the cursor in the `gvim` window has indeed moved to the right location, but the window-in-focus (or active window, or current window or window-in-selection) has not been shifted to `gvim` window. I have to manually select the vim window either by mouse or by keyboard shortcuts such as `Alt+tab`.

On the other hand its annoying to see that, if I used `kile` editor to setup this inverse search, the focus is indeed being shifted to `kile`!

Additionally, there was no such problem with forward search, setup from Vim using the instructions to invoke okular by a system call to `okular --unique ....` according to these [instructions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/83649/26662). The focus indeed shifted to okular as expected.

PS: I am on Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Does `gvim` take the focus but the window does not rise? Or does it not take the focus? Either way, this is probably a matter for your window manager and will depend on which one you're using. It *may* be that you can configure the command to tell `gvim` to request focus/rise. But whether that's permitted will still depend on your window manager in the end.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to switch to Emacs, a real editor after all?

Comment: @cfr yes you are right. my problem is only that the window doesn't focus and also doesn't raise. My window manager is exactly what Ubuntu-14.04 LTS gives by default. And I strongly believe there should be a way.

Comment: @KeksDose Please don't bring vim/emacs flame wars here. Really.

Comment: Since I use Kile and it just works, I'm not likely to be much help. But I could, if I needed to, set Kile-specific settings to control focus using my window manager's option. As it is, I have focus-stealing-prevention set to 'Low' globally anyway. I deliberately have focus and raise distinct (click to raise, but focus follows mouse). So the global stuff seems to be enough for my Okular/Kile combo. (It is sometimes slow, but only if the window hasn't been active for a while.) I suspect your best bet is to ask on an Ubuntu board rather than here.

Comment: Strange that it works with Kile. Either it has different settings or Kile signals the window manager and gvim doesn't. Maybe? But you can surely override the default for gvim if you want to. Even if you had to write a script to incorporate an explicit focus/raise command to the window manager.

Comment: @cfr thanks for the analysis. I will wait for a while and then go for asking on Ubuntu board.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution for this problem. The idea is to use [xdotool](https://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/). See also [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/486345/13936) on askubuntu.com.

## 1. Install xdotool

On Ubuntu you can do this by

```
sudo apt install xdotool
```

## 2. Write a bash script

Save the following script as gvim-raise.sh somewhere on your `$PATH`.

```
#!/bin/bash    
gvim --servername GVIM --remote +$1 $2 ; xdotool search --name "/* - GVIM" windowactivate
```

Make it executable by

```
chmod +x gvim-raise.sh
```

## 3. Configure Okular

Put this line in Okular's editor option

```
gvim-raise.sh %l %f
```

Then everything should work as expected.

Comment: Just a caveat -- If you install okular from flatpak -- https://flathub.org/apps/details/org.kde.okular This will not work. flatpak's sandbox model will stop you from calling your script.