# how to focus Vim when doing pdf-to-tex search from Okular

Tags: forward-inverse-search, vim, okular

When working with Latex files, I use Vim to edit the tex file and Okular to view the corresponding pdf. I have pdf-to-tex search (which requires running Vim as a server, and compiling the tex file with Synctex) configured by making `vim --remote +%l %f` my custom editor command in Okular (`Settings  Configure Okular  Editor  Command`). This works, but it does not focus Vim, and I remain in Okular.

I would like to focus Vim when I do this search, so I can immediately start editing the tex file. How can I achieve this?

**Note**: This question is basically the same as [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/317892/window-focus-problem-during-inverse-search-from-okular-to-gvim), except I am using Vim, not gVim. And the only answer posted to that question does not work with Vim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use `xdotool`, which is a command-line tool that can interact with windows.

**step 1: save Vim's window ID to a file**

Run this Vim command after Vim is started as a server:

```vim
:call system('xdotool getactivewindow > /tmp/vim_wid.txt')
```

*Explanation*: The shell command `xdotool getactivewindow` will output the active window ID, and the command `xdotool getactivewindow > /tmp/vim_wid.txt` will save that window ID to the file `/tmp/vim_wid.txt` (as an example).

**step 2: use an `xdotool` command after your `vim --remote-silent` command to focus the Vim window**

You can set your custom Okular editor command (`Settings  Configure Okular  Editor  Command`) to be this:

```
/bin/sh -c "vim --remote +%l %f && cat /tmp/vim_wid.txt | xargs xdotool windowactivate"
```

*Explanation*: The shell command `xdotool windowactive window_ID` will activate the window with ID *window_ID*. So, if you want to activate the Vim window, you can pipe the window ID from `/tmp/vim_wid.txt` into that command with `cat /tmp/vim_wid.txt | xargs xdotool windowactivate`. The `/bin/sh -c "command"` formatting is necessary for the command to be interpreted correctly.