# table badly too wide

Tags: tables, tabularx, latexmk, tabulary, pdfsync

I got a bad problem with the width of my table. I can't get the point why its so wide.

I'm using `latexmk`.

Here's my code:

```
\documentclass[final,12pt,abstracton,oneside,a4paper,
bibliography=totocnumbered,
listof=totoc]{scrreprt}


% my imports
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[babel,german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage[ngerman, num]{isodate}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{pdfsync}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[square]{natbib}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{rotating}

% import from used template
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[right]{eurosym}
\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage[pdfpagelabels=true]{hyperref}

% define paper geometry
\geometry{a4paper, left=20mm, top=27mm, right=20mm, bottom=27mm, headsep=10mm,bindingoffset=10mm}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{
  \lhead{}
   \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
  }

\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{\leftmark}
\chead{}
\rhead{\thepage}
\cfoot{}

\begin{document}
% titlepage toc tof and so on...
\begin{table}[h]
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lX}
  \hline
    Event & Description \\
  \hline
    \texttt{SomeOfMyEvents} & Description of the events goes here...
    large large texts should be here line 1
    large large texts should be here line 2
    large large texts should be here line 3
    large large texts should be here line 4
    large large texts should be here line 5
    large large texts should be here line 6
    large large texts should be here line 7
    large large texts should be here line 8
    large large texts should be here line 9
    large large texts should be here line 10
    large large texts should be here \\
  \hline
  \end{tabularx}
  \caption{caption}
  \label{tab:cap}
\end{table}
% ...
\end{document}
```

and my result looks like this:
[image]

The rule wit the romic II is my textwidth. How you can see this table is much wider than textwidh. If I try to set the width to `0.5\textwidth` only the hline's of the table will be as half as long, the columns stay the same.

I even tried wit package `tabulary`, `tabu`, and `tabular*` with `p{4cm}p{4cm}` didn't work either. I'm running out of ideas. I hope some one has a better idea on this purpose.

### EDIT:

I added more real code. Now only the name of the events and the content of my description varies.

### EDIT #2:

Due to comments i added the complete preamble of my document. The picture i show is the output of my code shown above.

Comment: this table ist just an example. What I really needing is `lX` because the X should held long lines of text. But it is generating the table wrong too. According to the documentation of `tabularx|y` the table should have the width of my text and the X should be automatically set. Specifying two XX doesn't work properly either.

Comment: I edited my code to provide a more realistic example. However this has no impact on my table.

Comment: Clearly the code you posted does not produce the image you show of the problem. Please edit the question so your code is a complete example from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}` and show the image _of the output from that code_

Comment: The new example generates an error `! LaTeX Error: \l@subfigure undefined.` Once latex generates an error you should not be surprised about any typeset result, tex's recovery actions try to let it continue they do not try to make a sensible typeset result

Comment: Your right, i don't using subfigure. That was a peace from a template I used. Anyway this has no impact on my result. I edited my code above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for posting a full MWE. The culprit turns out to be the `pdfsync` package. I can't tell which of the *many* other packages you also load it interacts with badly, but the upshot of its presence is the terrible look of the table.

The user guide of the `pdfsync` package suggests that

> in case of severe conflicts with another package, try instead
>
> ```
> \usepackage[novbox]{pdfsync}
> ```

Sure enough, adding the `novbox` option solves the immediate problem.

I honestly don't know enough about the `pdfsync` package to tell you if there's a better solution. Quoting from the "Bugs" section of the package's user guide:

> `pdfsync` uses extremely [sensitive] code. You should not use `pdfsync` on final documents because it can change the layout rather significantly (different page/line breaks are the most obvious changes).

This isn't the most confidence-inspiring statement, is it?

Comment: Oh thanks a lot! That's the snag! This solved my problem.

Comment: I'm using pdfsync during the creation of my documents because it simply easier in combination of Vim. However i'll comment out pdfsync in my final version!

Comment: As noted in the `pdfsync` docs, this functionality _has_ been built-in to `pdflatex` for some time. It's called `synctex`, and you might find this question helpful in setting it up with vim: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2941/how-to-setup-synctex-with-vim-pdflatex-and-an-open-source-pdf-viewer-under-linu

Comment: It's simple: `pdfsync` should never be used. Activate `pdfsync=1` in the command line and all will go smooth, with synchronization between input and output.