# Tabular* environment in harvard-thesis template

Tags: tables, document-classes, pdfsync

I have one issue with tables in harvard-thesis template version 0.4. I cannot set column width with column types such as p, m, b or even custom column types. If I set width to any of the columns, the column fills the entire text width irrespective of the value I use.

I am building with xelatex

[image]

Contents of file `harvard-thesis.cls`:

```
% https://github.com/TruePath/LaTeX-template-for-Harvard-dissertation/blob/master/harvard-thesis.cls
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e} 
%################################################################################
%################################## harvard-thesis.cls starts here ##############
%################################################################################
\ProvidesClass{harvard-thesis}[2012/04/05 v0.4 Harvard University Thesis Class]  
\LoadClass[12pt, oneside, letterpaper]{book}
\RequirePackage{graphicx} 
\RequirePackage{hyperref} 
\RequirePackage{listings} 
\RequirePackage{afterpage}
 \hypersetup{   linktocpage,     colorlinks,   
citecolor=Crimson,     filecolor=black,     linkcolor=black,  
 urlcolor=Crimson, }
  \lstset{  float=h,     frame=single,  
basicstyle=\scriptsize,     breaklines=true, 
postbreak=\raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\ensuremath{\color{red}
\hookrightarrow\space}} 
}
  \RequirePackage[title,titletoc]{appendix}
 \usepackage{lipsum}
  \usepackage{array,etoolbox}
 \preto\tabular{\setcounter{magicrownumbers}
{0}
}
 \newcounter{magicrownumbers}
 \newcommand\rownumber{\stepcounter{magicrownumbers}
\arabic{magicrownumbers}
}
  \usepackage{makecell}
  \usepackage[colorinlistoftodos, textwidth=4cm, shadow]{todonotes}
  \RequirePackage[centertags]{amsmath}
 \RequirePackage{amssymb}
 \RequirePackage[numbers,comma,sort&compress]{natbib}
 \RequirePackage[small, md, sc]{titlesec}
 \RequirePackage[tight,nice]{units}
 \RequirePackage{verbatim}
 \RequirePackage{textcomp}
  \RequirePackage{color}
 \definecolor{Crimson}
{rgb}
{0.6471, 0.1098, 0.1882}
  \RequirePackage{url}
 \RequirePackage[titles]{tocloft}
 \setcounter{tocdepth}
{1}
 \renewcommand{\cftchapfont}
{\normalsize \scshape}
  \renewcommand\bibname{References}
 \renewcommand\listfigurename{Listing of figures}
  \RequirePackage{pdfsync}
  \usepackage[closeFloats, noSeparatorLine]{fltpage}
 \RequirePackage{afterpage}
  \usepackage{float}
  \synctex=1 \RequirePackage{bibentry}
  \nobibliography*          \RequirePackage{lettrine}
 \RequirePackage[width=5in, letterpaper]{geometry}
  \RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
  \pagestyle{plain}
 \RequirePackage[palatino]{quotchap}
 \definecolor{chaptergrey}
{rgb}
{0.6,0,0}
 \RequirePackage{titling}
 \RequirePackage{setspace}
  \RequirePackage{booktabs,tabularx}
 \RequirePackage[labelfont={sf,bf,small}
,textfont={sf,small}
,justification=RaggedRight,margin=0pt, figurewithin=section, tablewithin=section]{caption}
 \onehalfspacing  \parindent 12pt \RequirePackage{mathspec}
  \RequirePackage{graphicx}
 \RequirePackage{enumitem}
 \usepackage[no-sscript]{xltxtra}
  \newcommand{\add}
[1]{\textcolor{orange}
{\ul{#1}
}
}
 \newcommand{\remove}
[1]{\textcolor{red}
{\textst{#1}
}
}
 \newcommand{\change}
[2]{\textcolor{red}
{\textst{#1}
}
\textcolor{green}
{\ul{#2}
}
}
 \newcommand{\hide}
[1]{}
  \RequirePackage{xunicode,soul}
  \def\degreeyear#1{\gdef\@degreeyear{#1}
}
 \def\degreemonth#1{\gdef\@degreemonth{#1}
}
 \def\degree#1{\gdef\@degree{#1}
}
 \def\advisor#1{\gdef\@advisor{#1}
}
 \def\department#1{\gdef\@department{#1}
}
 \def\field#1{\gdef\@field{#1}
}
 \def\university#1{\gdef\@university{#1}
}
 \def\universitycity#1{\gdef\@universitycity{#1}
}
 \def\universitystate#1{\gdef\@universitystate{#1}
}
   \renewcommand{\maketitle}
{   \singlespacing  \thispagestyle{empty}
    \vspace*{\fill}
 \vspace{150pt}
 \begin{center}
    \Huge \textcolor{Crimson}
{\textit{\thetitle}
}
 \normalsize \\ \sc \vspace{100pt}
    a dissertation presented \\ by\\    \theauthor\\ to\\ The \@department\\    \vspace{12pt}
    in partial fulfillment of the requirements\\    for the degree of\\ \@degree\\      in the subject of\\ \@field\\   \vspace{12pt}
    \@university\\ \@universitycity, \@universitystate\\    \@degreemonth\ \@degreeyear     \end{center}
 \vspace*{\fill}
 }
  \newcommand{\copyrightpage}
{   \newpage \thispagestyle{empty}
 \vspace*{\fill}
    \sc \noindent \copyright~\textit{\@degreeyear \hspace{3pt}
~- \theauthor}
 \\     \noindent All rights reserved.  \vspace*{\fill}
 \newpage \rm }
  \newcommand{\abstractpage}
{   \newpage    \pagenumbering{roman}
    \setcounter{page}
{3}
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \lhead{Thesis advisor: \@advisor}
 \rhead{\@author}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}
{0.0pt}
    \begin{center}
    \vspace*{1pt}
    \Large \textcolor{Crimson}
{\textit{\@title}
}
 \normalsize\\  \vspace*{15pt}
    \sc Abstract \\ \rm     \end{center}
    \doublespace    \input{frontmatter/abstract}
    \doublespace    \newpage \lhead{}
 \rhead{}
    \cfoot{\thepage}
    \onehalfspacing }
  \newcommand{\dedicationpage}
{   \pagestyle{fancy}
    \newpage \thispagestyle{fancy}
 \vspace*{\fill}
    \sc \noindent \input{frontmatter/dedication}
    \vspace*{\fill}
 \newpage \rm   }
  \newcommand{\authorlist}
{   \pagestyle{fancy}
    \newpage    \thispagestyle{fancy}
    \chapter*{Author List}
    \noindent \input{frontmatter/authorlist}
    \newpage \rm    }
  \newcommand{\acknowledgments}
{   \chapter*{Acknowledgments}
    \noindent   \input{frontmatter/thanks}
    \vspace*{\fill}
    \newpage    \setcounter{page}
{1}
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
}
     \providecommand\newthought[1]{    \addvspace{1.0\baselineskip plus 0.5ex minus 0.2ex}
    \noindent\textsc{#1}
}
     \usepackage{tikz}

%################################################################################
%################################## harvard-thesis.cls ends here ##############
%################################################################################
```

A sample document (must be compiled with XeLaTeX):

```
\documentclass{harvard-thesis}
  \begin{document}
 \pagestyle{plain}
  \begin{table}
 \scriptsize \caption{My table}
 \label{table1}
 \centering \begin{tabular*}
{\textwidth}
{|c|c|c|p{.3\textwidth}
|p{5cm}
|}
\hline 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & consectetuer adipiscing elit. Morbi commodo, ipsum sed pharetra gravida, orci magna rhoncus neque, id pulvinar odio lorem non turpis. Nullam sit amet enim. Suspendisse id velit vitae ligula volutpat condimentum. Aliquam erat volutpat. Sed quis velit. Nulla facilisi. Nulla libero. Vivamus pharetra posuere sapien. Nam consectetuer. Sed aliquam, nunc eget euismod ullamcorper, lectus nunc ullamcorper orci, fermentum bibendum enim nibh eget ipsum. Donec porttitor ligula eu dolor. Maecenas vitae nulla consequat libero cursus venenatis. Nam magna enim, accumsan eu, blandit sed, blandit a, eros.\\ \hline \end{tabular*}
   \bigskip \caption{With \texttt{@{\string\extracolsep\{\string\fill\}
\}
}
}
}
 \begin{tabular*}
{\textwidth}
{@{\extracolsep{\fill}
}
 cccp{.3\textwidth}
p{5cm}
@{}
}
 \hline  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & consectetuer adipiscing elit. Morbi commodo, ipsum sed pharetra   gravida, orci magna rhoncus neque, id pulvinar odio lorem non turpis. Nullam sit amet enim. Suspendisse id velit vitae ligula volutpat condimentum. Aliquam erat volutpat. Sed quis velit. Nulla facilisi. \\  \hline  \end{tabular*}
  \end{table}
  \end{document}
```

The harvard-thesis.cls is originally from Jordan here https://github.com/suchow/Dissertate/blob/master/Dissertate.cls

but it seems to have been updated. I have included its contents in the code.

Comment: Could you please provide a complete, compilable document? This should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`.

Comment: The `huthesis` - class seems to be available here: [huthesis](https://math.dartmouth.edu/~ahb/thesis/format.html)

Comment: Hi and welcome, why was your code example one single line?

Comment: Thanks @Johannes_B. I am not sure if its my browser I struggle to format it

Comment: Thank you for posting a working example! At the same time, much of your code does not seem to be relevant to the question you're asking here. Please limit the example to code required for your issue to appear. You can have a look at the [guide for how to minimalize your code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3225).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) It's not necessary to sign your questions (as [there is already a box with your username below it](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures)) or to begin them with a greeting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Note: I've revised this answer completely after the OP posted the code of the thesis class in question.)

Thanks for posting the code of the thesis class you use. It turns out that this class file loads the `pdfsync` package, which is known to cause all kinds of problems. In my answer to an earlier posting entitled [table badly too wide](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/187080/5001), I wrote the following:

---

The user guide of the `pdfsync` package suggests that

> in case of severe conflicts with another package, try instead
>
> ```
> \usepackage[novbox]{pdfsync}
> ```

Sure enough, adding the `novbox` option solves the immediate problem.

I honestly don't know enough about the `pdfsync` package to tell you if there's a better solution. Quoting from the "Bugs" section of the package's user guide:

> `pdfsync` uses extremely [sensitive] code. You should not use `pdfsync` on final documents because it can change the layout rather significantly (different page/line breaks are the most obvious changes).

This isn't the most self-confident -- or confidence-inspiring -- statement, is it?

---

Returning to your document: There seems to be no reason for why your thesis class would load this package. I therefore strongly suggest that you delete the statement `\RequirePackage{pdfsync}`. If you delete the statement, the modified `tabular*` environment compiles fine.

Comment: It does not work, I'll include the complete code below

Comment: @George - After you posted the code of the file `harvard-thesis.cls`, I rewrote my answer completely. It turns out that the culprit, so to say, is the fact that the package `pdfsync` is being loaded. If you comment out (or delete) that instruction, the table is generated without further surprises.