# faulty german hyphenation in XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, hyphenation

As you see in the picture beneath some words, not only "Gegenüberstellung" the hyphenation is not correct, at the right site of the paper. Unfortunately the different questions relating this topic here on TexExchange did not solve the issue. To help me out I use `Si-cher-heits-ma-nage-ment" but it's not practical for the whole document. XeLateX and System "Times new Roman" Font.

To be more precise: The word "Ge-gen-über-stel-lung" should break at "Ge-" or at least at "Gegen-". mostly it works but in every Section there will be a handful of Words where you need to do the break manually with Latex-Syntax: "Ge-gen-über-stel-lung" or it will be written to the edge of the paper or break to late in the middle like "Gegenüberstellung".

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,titlepage,listof=totoc,bibliography=totoc]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=4cm, right=2cm, top=4cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\babelprovide[hyphenrules=ngerman-x-latest]{ngerman}
\usepackage[german=quotes,autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{pdfsync}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{fontspec}                   
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\defaultfontfeatures[\rmfamily,\sffamily]{Ligatures=TeX}
\addtokomafont{sectionentry}{\mdseries} 
\setkomafont{sectioning}{\bfseries}     
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\newcommand{\capquelle}[1]{%
    \par\parbox{\captionwidth}{\raggedright\bigskip Quelle: #1}%
}
\usepackage{hvfloat}
\usepackage{footnote}
\usepackage[hang,multiple,bottom,stable]{footmisc} 
\setlength{\footnotesep}{2pt} 
\setlength{\footheight}{22cm} 
\setlength{\footnotemargin}{.8em} 
\interfootnotelinepenalty=9999 
\usepackage{nicefrac} 
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{mdwlist}
\linespread{1.5}
\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.3em plus 0.5em minus 0.6em}
\input{app/skripte/weitereEbene}
\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}
\usepackage[intoc]{nomencl}
\renewcommand{\nomname}{Abkürzungsverzeichnis}
\setlength{\nomlabelwidth}{.50\textwidth}
\renewcommand{\nomlabel}[1]{#1 \dotfill}
\setlength{\nomitemsep}{-\parsep}
\makenomenclature
\fancypagestyle{plain}%
    \fancyhf{} 
    \fancyhead[C]{\thepage}
    \fancyfoot{}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt} 
\pagestyle{fancy} 
    \fancyhf{} 
    \fancyhead[C]{\thepage}
    \fancyfoot{}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\begin{document}
    \renewcommand{\figurename}{Abbildung}           
    \pagenumbering{Roman}                           
\renewcommand{\refname}{Literaturverzeichnis}       
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\arraybackslash}X}              
\newpage
\restoregeometry 
\setcounter{page}{2} 
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\printnomenclature
\newpage
\listoffigures
\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}

\subsection{Aufbau}
Im zweiten Kapitel wird zunächst der Begriff \textit{Bring Your Own Device} (BYOD) definiert. Darauffolgend wird dargelegt welche Fokusse gesetzt werden sollen und Schlussfolgerungen gezogen, sowie eine Sicherheitsrichtlinie abgeleitet. Welche als Grundlage einer Gegenüberstellung mit etablierten Konzepten dient, sodass Strategien erörtert werden können. Darauffolgend wird in Kapitel Drei eine Diskussion der Vor- und Nachteile von \textit{Bring Your Own Device} aus unterschiedlichen Sichten.


\end{document}
```

Log (only warnings, because it's too long):

```
Class scrartcl Warning: Usage of package `fancyhdr' together
(scrartcl)              with a KOMA-Script class is not recommended.
(scrartcl)              I'd suggest to use 
(scrartcl)              package `scrlayer' or `scrlayer-scrpage', because
(scrartcl)              they support KOMA-Script classes.
(scrartcl)              With `fancyhdr' several features of class `scrartcl'
(scrartcl)              like options `headsepline', `footsepline' or command
(scrartcl)              `\MakeMarkcase' and the commands `\setkomafont' and
(scrartcl)              `\addtokomafont' for the page style elements need
(scrartcl)              explicite user intervention to work.
(scrartcl)              Nevertheless, using requested
(scrartcl)              package `fancyhdr' on input line 17.
----
Package babel Warning: No hyphenation patterns were preloaded for
(babel)                the language `German (new orthography)' into the format.

(babel)                Please, configure your TeX system to add them and
(babel)                rebuild the format. Now I will use the patterns
(babel)                preloaded for english instead on input line 47.

Package babel Info: \l@ngerman = using hyphenrules for english
(babel)             (\language0) on input line 48.
Package babel Info: Making " an active character on input line 121.
)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/locale/de/babel-ngerman.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/locale/de/babel-german.tex
Package babel Info: Importing basic data for ngerman
(babel)             from babel-de.ini. Reported on input line 11.
))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/csquotes/csquotes.sty
Package: csquotes 2019-12-06 v5.2j context-sensitive quotations (JAW)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty
Package: etoolbox 2019/09/21 v2.5h e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count178
)
\csq@reset=\count179
\csq@gtype=\count180
\csq@glevel=\count181
\csq@qlevel=\count182
\csq@maxlvl=\count183
\csq@tshold=\count184
\csq@ltx@everypar=\toks25
```

Docker font install:

```
RUN && microdnf -y update \
    && microdnf -y install \
            texlive-scheme-basic \
...
        curl \
        cabextract \
        xorg-x11-font-utils \
        fontconfig \
        && rpm -i 'https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/mscorefonts2/rpms/msttcore-fonts-installer-2.6-1.noarch.rpm'
```

Comment: Make a small but  *complete* example and show the log-file.

Comment: The preamble is incomplete as it is not shown what font you're selecting; in the image it's a kind of Times, I guess. It's impossible to help you if you don't show a way to reproduce your image. I tried and I can't.

Comment: You have used  `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` but tagged the question {xetex}  are you using xelatex? all hyphenation will be incorrect if you use T1 encoding with xelatex, delete the `fontenc` usage.

Comment: Thanks for your interest. Unfortunately deleting \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} did not change hyphenations. I provided more Info above.

Comment: I tried to run the example but got `! LaTeX Error: File ``app/skripte/modsBiblatex2018.tex' not found.` please provide an example that produces the bad hyphenation without error

Comment: The original script has many dependencies, I already removed. I removed this one, too.

Comment: if I delete the bibliography lines that generate errors and not needed for this example [i get this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFCHJ.png) which does not match what you show.

Comment: Package babel Warning: No hyphenation patterns were preloaded for
(babel)                the language `German (new orthography)' into the format.  means that somehow you have built a format that does not support German. you should be able to install texilve-full using your linux package manager

Comment: Thanks, I installed texlive-scheme-basic and added the packages independently. I try to install the full package, it will take a moment.

Comment: What's wrong with hyphenating `Gegenüberstellung` as `Gegenüber-stellung`, as is done in the screenshot you posted?

Comment: The word "Ge-gen-über-stel-lung" should break at "Ge-" or at least at "Gegen-". mostly it works but in every Section there will be a handful of Words where you need to do the break manually with Latex-Syntax: "Ge\-gen\-über\-stel\-lung" or it will be written to the edge of the paper or break to late in the middle like "Gegenüberstellung"

Comment: unrelated but pdfsync is obsolete, synctex is now included directly.

Comment: @dhd80 - Please see the answer i just posted. As I show in the answer, `babel` has no problems finding *all valid* hyphenation points in both `Gegenüberstellung`and `Sicherheitsmanagement`, and it doesn't come up with any invalid hyphenation points.

Comment: Incidentally, why on earth are you loading the `pdfsync` package?? See [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/187086/5001) (shameless self-citation alert!) for an overview of what all can go wrong if one loads this wretched package. An excerpt from the package's user guide: "You should not use `pdfsync` on final documents because it can change the layout rather significantly (different page/line breaks are the most obvious changes)." I know of no redeeming feature of this package. In short, *stop using this package. Now!*

Comment: It worked! Thanks for your input. But I'm not sure it was DavidCarlisle or Mico's answer which fixed the issue. I will figure that out and post it.

Comment: @dhd80 - My money would be on David Carlisle's comments getting the job done...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like David Carlisle suggested a simple missing package was the reason. instead of using texlive-scheme-full I digged deeper and found, package texlive-hyphen-german was needed, if you choose using texlive-scheme-basic. With this package installed hyphenation works fine.