# pst-vowel: "missing } inserted" if \ncline is present

Tags: pstricks, auto-pst-pdf

On a freshly-updated MikTeX on Windows 10, this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf,pst-vowel}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{vowel}[ipanew]
\putcvowel{something}{1}
\putcvowel{something}{2}
\end{vowel}
\ncline{->}{v1}{v2}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

gives an error (compiled with `lualatex -enable-write18`):

```
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text>
}
l.10 \end{figure}
```

I think this used to work in the past. Any idea what the issue is?
Removing the `ncline` command fixes it, but obviously also gets rid of the arrow I intended to draw.

Comment: try `\usepackage[crop=off]{auto-pst-pdf}`. see if the answers here work for you: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2941/how-to-setup-synctex-with-vim-pdflatex-and-an-open-source-pdf-viewer-under-linu

Comment: Your example is a bit too minimal. There is nothing for auto-pst-pdf to do and so the warning is quite normal.

Comment: Did some more debugging and I found out that the error actually came from a completely different source -- I've now edited the question to include the larger problem. Turns out that the -autopp warning was actually a red herring...

Comment: That does not really work with `lualatex`. Use `xelatex` instead and without `auto-pst-pdf`

Answer (score 1):

If you still need `lualatex` then you can define an external document
which will be run with `xelatex` and insert automatically the created PDF:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dtk-extern,pst-vowel}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{externalDocument}[
    compiler=xelatex,
    copyToExampleDir=false,
    crop,
    code=false,
    showFilename=false,
]{demo}
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{pst-vowel}
\begin{document}
\begin{vowel}[ipanew]
\putcvowel{something}{1}
\putcvowel{something}{2}
\end{vowel}
\ncline{->}{v1}{v2}
\end{document}
\end{externalDocument}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

run with `lualatex --shell-escape <file>`

There is also a package `auto-pst-pdf-lua`, but it doesn't really help. The internal run is done with `dviluslatex` which cannot handle OpenType fonts.

Comment: It does not make sense to load `pst-vowel` in the embedding document if you cannot use it there.