# How to make a PDF viewer jump to the latest tex update?

Tags: pdf, vim, vim-latex, evince

The `vim-latex-live-preview` Vim plugin and with `:LLPStartPreview` periodically refreshes the resultant PDF (by calling pdflatex on the tex file).

After a refresh the location displayed in the PDF is unchanged (as one would expect, perhaps?).

The PDF viewer I'm using is `evince`, though I'm happy to change. `zathura` looks interesting.

**What I need:** After making a change in the source through vim, at the next refresh the PDF viewer should jump to the latest change. Much like `Tex Studio` does.

The only way I can imagine this is possible is to tell the PDF viewer to jump to a specific line/page/section.

**Q:** Is there a Vim plugin which accomplishes this?

**Q:** Is there a PDF viewer which allows jumping to a specific location in a file after a reload?

Comment: Looks like my question is going nowhere, unfortunately...

Comment: I haven't done this yet but these two links seem related: https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Open_pdf_to_the_current_location_in_a_LaTeX_file and https://youtu.be/NwnYHoNtfJ0?t=332

Comment: Related question: [pdftex - How to setup synctex with vim, pdflatex and an open-source PDF-viewer under Linux? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2941/how-to-setup-synctex-with-vim-pdflatex-and-an-open-source-pdf-viewer-under-linu/412366#412366)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't tell how vim-latex's preview work, but setup forward and backward search in vim can be done with little configuration using  zathura, based on this gist :

https://gist.github.com/vext01/16df5bd48019d451e078

Your insight is right. First, you ought to compile your pdf with `synctex` enabled (I imagine vim-latex does this automatically).
Then, `zathura` has the `--synctex-forward` option that allows you to specify a location on the pdf to jump to. This is the "forward" direction. On the other side, there is `-x command` which tells zathura to execute `command` when you `CTRL+Click`. Finally vim can be launched with `--servername nameserver` so you can call it from outside (zathura's `-x` option) and jump to a specific location -- "backward" direction.

The gist gives a good implementation of this. Bellow is my slightly modified version :

- [vimura](https://github.com/perelo/dotfiles/blob/master/vim/vimura)
- [vimscript function](https://github.com/perelo/dotfiles/blob/master/vim/plugin/prose_functions.vim#L10-L22)
- `nnoremap <buffer> <leader>p :call Synctex()<CR>`
- `alias vim="vim --servername vimd"`

Basically,

- I always startup `vim` *than* `<leader>p` to open the pdf in the right place.
- The `vim` alias automatically sets up a server, allowing external programs to talk to vim.
- The mapping calls `Synctex()` which calls `vimura` external script, passing the `--synctex-forward` option and data from vim's context (`line('.')`...)
- `vimura` calls zathura with both `-x` setup with vim and `--synctex-forward` retrieved from argument.
- In the end, `<leader>p` moves the pdf to the right location, `Ctrl+click` moves vim to the right location.

Hope it makes it not too confusing.