# How to get synctex forward searching to work with vim and zathura on macOS?

Tags: pdf, forward-inverse-search, vim-latex

Using the vimtex plugin, forward searching (from the .tex file to the .pdf) works with Skim but not with zathura.

In nvim, the error `Vimtex: Viewer cannot find Zathura window ID!` appears. This [seems to be caused by](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex/issues/1737) a problem with `xdotool`, which does not assign a window id to the zathura window.

But in Terminal, the following command doesn't do anything either:

```
zathura --synctex-forward 100:10:mwe.tex mwe.pdf
```

Has anyone been successful in getting forward search to zathura to work on macOS?

Comment: did you find anything that works?

Comment: No, currently using Skim which works perfectly. There is talk over at the Vimtex Github of a patch.

Comment: Can you please link a guide which details setting up skim? Also, what are the differences you have observed between skim and zathura?

Comment: See the vimtex documentation https://github.com/lervag/vimtex/blob/master/doc/vimtex.txt.   The following in your .vimrc should do the trick: 
let g:tex_flavor='latex'
let g:vimtex_compiler_progname = 'nvr'
let g:vimtex_view_method = 'skim'

Additionally, I'm using the following settings in Skim > Preferences > Sync:  Preset: Custom;   Command: nvim; Arguments:   -remote-silent %line "%file"    Note that I am using nvim. 
If using nvim you should have neovim-remote (a plugin) installed. 

Zathura is more lightweight and can be customised to use the same colorscheme as your vim.

Comment: For other editors see also: [pdftex - How to setup synctex with vim, pdflatex and an open-source PDF-viewer under Linux? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2941/how-to-setup-synctex-with-vim-pdflatex-and-an-open-source-pdf-viewer-under-linu/412366#412366)