# Inverse search from Zathura to .tex file

Tags: forward-inverse-search, vim

With the help of someone on this stack I was able to configure vim so that it launches with a server name that is the filename it opens. For example, if I run `vim filename.tex`, vim will launch with the server name "filename". My issue now is using Zathura as a previewer when I compile and preview my .tex file, I want to be able to inverse search. This requires me to be able to configure Zathura so that the instance of Zathura that is previewing filename.pdf will inverse search to the vim window with the "filename" server.

Currently in my `zathurarc` I have the following,

`set synctex-editor-command "vim --servername +%{1} --remote-silent +%{line} %{input}"`

This does not work though. So I am hoping someone here will have a suggestion to get me on the right track? Is this even possible?

EDIT: The terminal with vim open returns this error:
[image]

Comment: Hello, I can't make a precise answer atm, but I remember [this gist](https://gist.github.com/vext01/16df5bd48019d451e078) in which we had some discussions and led to my configuration. Hope it helps.

There is also [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/603386/193655)