# How to use the color package with dvips option together with the graphicx package?

Tags: graphics, color

I have a problem with the bounding box of my graphics.

Example 1 below, where I only include a PNG image works fine.

Example 2 below, where I also have `\usepackage[dvips]{color}` in order to include a PS file, does not work - the PNG image is blown up!

#### Code example 1

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \includegraphics[scale=0.7]{irg.png}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

#### Code example 2

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[dvips]{color}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \includegraphics[scale=0.7]{irg.png}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
        \includegraphics{irg2.ps}
 \end{figure}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: In general I would recommend you to use the extended `xcolor` package instead of `color`. It should support everything what `color` does and more.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot mix `.png` and `.eps` files in the same document. The short story is that

- if you're using `pdflatex` to compile your document then you can use `.png`, `.jpg` and `.pdf` pictures; while
- if you're using `latex` you can only include `.eps`.

The best solution is to [stick to pdflatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2811/is-there-any-reason-to-compile-to-dvi-rather-than-pdf-these-days) and use `epstopdf` to convert your `.eps` figure to a `.pdf` (or, if possible, generate directly a `.pdf` from your source application).

And you don't need to load `color` (or `xcolor`) to include figures.

Comment: In TeXlive 2010 (or before with the epstopdf package), you can use .eps figures with pdflatex. And XeLaTeX has been able to use both for while now. And the tool is also called `epstopdf` not `eps2pdf`. Not sure about .ps files directly though.

Comment: @frabjous, thanks for your comment. I've corrected the name of the tool.

Answer (score 8):

If `graphicx` is not told the output driver to use it will do its best at auto-detecting it. This is usually the best way to go by far.  However, by loading `color` *after* `graphicx` you've told `color` to use (presumably) another driver than the one `graphicx` initialised, thus leading to the conflict which caused your figure to "blow up".  (I say presumably because you'd need to identify your platform and your LaTeX compiler to know for sure.)

The solution is quite simple. Either,

1. remove the [dvips] driver option to `color` (do-able if you can convert irg2.ps to, say, pdf format first), or more simply,
2. load `graphicx` after loading `color`, i.e., swap the two `\usepackage` lines to allow `graphicx`'s driver auto-detection routine to initialise itself for the driver you intend to use.

As a footnote, I'd recommend looking into using `xcolor` rather than `color` if you possibly can.  It provides a more robust colour framework and cohabitates very much better with recent packages than `color` does.