# How to use tilde or space in includepdf filename?

Tags: spacing, paths, pdfpages, tilde

I'm trying to include a pdf in a document, using `pdfpages` package, but I'm having troubles when filename contains tilde or space.

e.g.

```
\includepdf[pages=-]{C:/Users/MYUSER~1/AppData/Local/Temp/mypdfpdf.pdf}

\includepdf[pages=-]{C:/Users/MYUSER FOO/AppData/Local/Temp/mypdfpdf.pdf}
```

I've tried to escape for example through `$\sim$` but it doesn't work...

Is it possible to escape tilde/space in the filename ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can try `\string~` for the tilde and enclosing the whole file name in a pair of double quotes `"` for the space.

Comment: @egreg: this should be an answer!

Comment: @Herbert Martin's already covers it.

Comment: See also David's answer on how to quote special characters in http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/53646/175

Answer (score 19, accepted):

About the tilde:
Apparently the `~` is taken in its usually meaning, not as literal `~`. I get a `` Package pdfpages Error: Cannot find file `test\nobreakspace {}it' `` error for a `test~it` file.
Taking the filename verbatim should help. This can be done by `\Verbdef` from the `newverbs` package:

```
\usepackage{newverbs}

% ...

\Verbdef\filename{C:/Users/MYUSER~1/AppData/Local/Temp/mypdfpdf.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=-]{\filename}
```

It is also possible to write `\string~` instead of `~` every time. You shouldn't use math symbols to "escape" these characters in filenames. Typesetting and file reading are two completely different things.

Finally you can use the e-TeX primitive `\detokenize{...}` to sanitize the file name:

```
\includepdf[pages=-]{\detokenize{C:/Users/MYUSER~1/AppData/Local/Temp/mypdfpdf.pdf}}
```

To allow spaces you need to wrap the filename in `" "`. At best you should avoid any spaces, tildes or any other special characters in filenames.

Comment: Actually it's generated through Sweave so I can't avoid tildes and spaces, but thanks this works fine ! :)

Comment: @Martin Scharrer - thanks for the `\Verbdef` tip. At my site I've got people who use two or more (!!!) blanks for directory names. FYI: two or more blanks in the directory name get shrunk down to one blank when using `\detokenize` with `\includepdf`.

Comment: Also, note that wrapping the filename in `" "` is likely supposed to _not_ include the extension, because I just got: `LaTeX Error: Unknown graphics extension: .pdf"`

Comment: @sdaau: The handling of double quotes depends on the distribution and the OS as far as I know. Try to use `{ }` instead if you have spaces. There you might want to exclude the extension, like `\includepdf[...]{{some file name}.pdf}`. This works because the TeX code scanes the filename and splits basename and extension. The braces protect the spaces but are removed when the content is matched during the scan.

Comment: For me, only `\includepdf{\detokenize{"spaces are fun".pdf}}` worked, not braces.

Comment: @user1338062: Well, having spaces in the file name makes it even more complicated. But `\includepdf{{"spaces are fun"}.pdf}` should be enough in this case. See the different answer to [How to include graphics with spaces in their path?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8422/2975)

Comment: @MartinScharrer for me also `\includepdf{{"spaces are fun"}.pdf}` did **not** work, but `\includepdf{\detokenize{"spaces are fun".pdf}}` did!

Answer (score 21):

Note: Because newer versions of LaTeX and `graphicx` (and therefore also `pdfpages`) do support file names with spaces on there own, this answer is only of historical interest. From November 2019 `grffile` is an empty stub for compatibility only.

Spaces at file names of PDF files at `\includegraphics` or `\includepdf` are allowed, if you are using package [grffile](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/grffile):

```
\usepackage{grffile}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
% …
\includepdf[pages=-]{test this.pdf}
```

And for more verbatim interpretation of the file name you may use `\detokenize`:

```
\usepackage{grffile}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
% …
\includepdf[pages=-]{\detokenize{test~this.pdf}}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work on Windows: `'LaTeX Warning: File \`../x y.pdf' not found on input line 55.'`

Comment: Neither method works for me on windows.

Answer (score 1):

If you have issues while uploading files with space in its name (ie test 1.pdf , test 2.jpg etc).

Before you use the file in includepdf function, you need to add double quotes before and after the filename (ie "test 1".pdf , "test 2".jpg etc).

```
\usepackage{grffile}

\usepackage{pdfpages}

\includepdf[pages=-]{"test this".pdf}
```

Comment: This one actually worked for me (Windows), and without using `grffile` even: `\includepdf[pages=-]{my/dir/"my file".pdf}` - Not sure what it does with spaces in the *dir* name.