# What are the allowed characters in filenames?

Tags: external-files, file-lookup, jobname

What characters can be used in filenames for the main document and input files, both `.tex` and images etc.? I'm not asking about which are recommended to be used, but about a list of all possible characters a user could ever use in a filename. This is important to know in order to support those in filename related packages (e.g. `currfile`, `svn-multi`, ...).

I can see two use cases here:

- On the command line, e.g. using `pdflatex <filename>`.
  Which might require single-quotes and/or `\` to escape characters special to the command line shell, but then maybe again for TeX.
- Inside (La)TeX itself, e.g. `\input{<filename>}`.

For example: The use of `%` in (main document) filenames seems not possible with LaTeX using TeXLive 2011 under Linux. A `pdflatex 'test%it.tex'` results in a prompt and entering `\relax` there gives: `` ! I can't find file `test'. ``. So the `%` is also used as comment character in this case.

There seems to be more going on with filenames on the command line because I got the following warning:

```
# pdflatex 'test$it*gdg!£$^&%_*(){.tex'
warning: test$it*gdg!£$^&%_*(){.tex: Unrecognized variable construct `$^'.
```

Comment: You may want to narrow down your main question to "which characters cannot be used in filenames, for `.tex` and image files, that are otherwise acceptable to the operating system?" I think there's little point in exploring characters that the operating system itself doesn't allow (e.g., `/`, `\ `, and `?`) for valid names of files, right?

Comment: @Mico: Thanks. That's a good point. The ``/`` and ``\`` however can be part of the "filename" if you include the path, which we should. Also `?` is valid for filenames under Linux, you just have to make sure it is masked and not taken as wildcard, e.g. `'test?it'` or `test\?it`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The filename syntax is one of the few explicitly system dependent parts of TeX-the-program.

In texlive (ie web2c tex) most characters are allowed (especially after the syntax was changed to allow `"` quoting names including spaces). Of course the characters are interpreted by TeX's macro expansion before being considered as possible filename characters, so `%` and friends need special handling.

This inputs `test%it.tex` on my texlive 2010 (using a cygwin bash shell in windows, but I imagine other command lines would be similar)

```
  pdflatex "\begingroup\lccode44=37 \lowercase{\endgroup\input test,it}"
```

The warning about `$` that you mention comes from kpathsea, as described in its manual

> 3.3.2 Variable expansion ‘$foo’ or ‘${foo}’ in a path element is replaced by (1) the value of an environment variable ‘foo’ (if
>   defined); (2) the value of ‘foo’ from ‘texmf.cnf’ (if defined); (3)
>   the empty string. If the character after the ‘$’ is alphanumeric or
>   ‘_’, the variable name consists of all consecutive such characters. If
>   the character after the ‘$’ is a ‘{’, the variable name consists of
>   everything up to the next ‘}’ (braces may not be nested around
>   variable names). Otherwise, Kpathsea gives a warning and ignores the
>   ‘$’ and its following character.

---

you can test kpathsea's handling with tests sch as

```
$ FOO=ZENV tex kps
This is TeX, Version 3.1415926 (Web2C 2010)
(./kps.tex (./a b c.tex
a b c found
) (./ZENV.tex
ZENV found
) )
No pages of output.
Transcript written on kps.log.
```

which shows that you can refer to environment variables from with tex, kps.tex is

```
\input "a b c.tex"

\catcode`\$=12

\input "$FOO.tex"

\bye
```

`a b c.tex` is

```
\immediate\write20{a b c found}
```

and ZENV.tex is

```
\immediate\write20{ZENV found}
```

Comment: Thanks. The `kpathsea` hint is very useful. Does this mean you can write `\input{$foo/myfile.tex}` where `foo` is an environment variable or in `texmf.cnf`?

Comment: Yes, I updated my answer with an example

Answer (score 2):

It gets interesting if you try characters beyond the first 128/256; e.g. XeTeX from TL2011 can not handle unicode characters (like "äöüß") in input filenames on Windows 7. But this is highly system dependent.

It's best to use only alphanum ASCII (i.e. [a-zA-Z0-9]) for filenames, as these will *always* work.