# How to use paths with space in usepackage?

Tags: packages, paths

I need to use an absolute path for my package.
One of the folder I use contains a space.
I cannot change the name of this folder.

**So, how can I use paths containing the space character in `usepackage` ?**

---

EDIT

I tried to put my path between double quotes (`"`) but then, Latex tries to open the `"<my path>".sty` !!

I am using `pdftex` (I don't know if this info is relevant).

Comment: Did you try to use quotes? `{"foo/other foo/foo"}`

Comment: You might find your answers here: [link](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34918/how-to-use-tilde-or-space-in-includepdf-filename)

Comment: Yes I tried, see the edit

Comment: It doesn't work. The error :`! LaTeX Error: \`File "<my path>".sty' not found.`

Comment: The argument to `usepackage` is a package _name_ not a file path. It sometimes half works (but usually gives a warning) if you use a path (whether or not there is a space) but it is always incorrect usage.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle So, how should I do if my package is not in the directory of the `.tex` file (and the path includes space characters). Thanks !

Comment: @Colas What method do you use for running LaTeX on your file? The terminal or a front end such as TeXworks or TeXStudio or whatever?

Comment: I use terminal for this problem. And I also use a front end (TeXShop).

Comment: @Colas The proper place for local packages in MacTeX is in `~/Library/texmf/` with the proper internal structure. Anything you put there will be found automatically.  See [How do I add a .sty file to my MacTeX/TeXShop installation?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10256)   Do you have some reason for *not* putting local packages there?

Comment: I'm quite surprised that no-one has stated the (for me) obvious answer: ***Never*** use file of directory names with spaces. ***Ever.*** Full stop. You'll save yourself an awful lot of botheration.

Comment: I can't do otherwise...

Comment: @Colas You mean you have a kind of compulsion such that you simply can't resist?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The initial statement is false:

> I need to use an absolute path for my package.

`\usepackage` does not take a path at all --- it takes a package name.

Set `TEXINPUTS` to include the folder in which you have placed `mdframed.sty` and then just use

```
\usepackage{myownmackage}
```

For TeX Live and other web2c based systems you can set `TEXINPUTS` either as an environment variable or (better) in your `texmf.cnf` file.

Comment: Isn't this a bad example given that it would make much more sense to use `tlmgr` to install it?

Comment: @cfr not sure why I used that package name, probably I just had it in another answer at the time. Changed to a non standard name.

Answer (score 5):

If you're an expert with the terminal, you can add a symbolic link to the directory with a space in its name:

```
mkdir -p ~/Library/texmf/tex/latex
ln -s "/path/to/the/folder/with/space in name" ~/Library/texmf/tex/latex/spaceinname
```

Then simply doing `\usepackage{mypackage}` will find the file `mypackage.sty` in the folder with a space in its name. You can use whatever name you prefer instead of `spaceinname`, so long as it doesn't contain spaces (but it could).

On GNU/Linux systems, the `Library/` part should be omitted, it's specific for MacTeX on Mac OS X.

Answer (score 1):

For example, if the path is /User/Bob/Google\ Drive/file.sty.

I think the simplest way is:

```
\usepackage{"/Users/Bob/Google\space Drive/file"}
```

I am using `Latex`. And it works.

Comment: `\usepackage` only takes a package name. If the package uses `\ProvidesPackage`, then LaTeX will generate a warning, if the name specified in `\ProvidesPackage` does not match the name in `\usepackage`.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek But it works for my `Latex` engine.

Comment: As David said above, it may half-work, but it is wrong and liable to break. If you want to use it yourself, fine. If it breaks, you get to keep all the itsy-bitsy teeny-weeny pieces in the funeral urn of your document. But please don't recommend this to others as they may not want funeral urns.

Comment: @cfr Thanks for your advice. I may use David's solution.