# Convert LaTeX (Tikz) Anki Note to .png Error

Tags: tikz-pgf, anki

Good morning.

I try to apply advice given on this [page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/320139/how-to-get-anki-working-with-tikz-based-packages) to be able to include drawings in Latex with Anki. But, for a reason of which I am unaware, Anki does not want to convert files.tex into.png.

It is possible to have a little of assistant  ? Thank you

Hardware :
Mac book pro os : El capitain

Anki error :

```
An error occurred. It may have been caused by a harmless bug, 
or your deck may have a problem. 
To confirm it's not a problem with your deck, please run Tools > Check Database. 
If that doesn't fix the problem, please copy the following
into a bug report:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "aqt/editor.pyc", line 434, in onCardLayout
  File "aqt/clayout.pyc", line 48, in __init__
  File "aqt/clayout.pyc", line 60, in redraw
  File "aqt/clayout.pyc", line 186, in selectCard
  File "aqt/clayout.pyc", line 199, in onCardSelected
  File "aqt/clayout.pyc", line 234, in renderPreview
  File "anki/cards.pyc", line 120, in q
  File "anki/cards.pyc", line 137, in _getQA
  File "anki/collection.pyc", line 529, in _renderQA
  File "anki/hooks.pyc", line 32, in runFilter
  File "anki/latex.pyc", line 41, in mungeQA
  File "anki/latex.pyc", line 61, in _imgLink
  File "anki/latex.pyc", line 107, in _buildImg
  File "shutil.pyc", line 82, in copyfile
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'/var/folders/v1/psh6j3c139x1wkj2k38_77v40000gn/T/anki_temp/tmp.png'
```

Add-ons Anki "Edit_Latex_build_process.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Edit LaTeX generation procedure
# Soren I. Bjornstad <soren.bjornstad@gmail.com>
# add-on Version 2, for Anki 2.0.27+

# I do not think this add-on is really eligible for copyright protection, since
# it simply overwrites a variable in Anki's code, but in case it is, you are
# free to do anything you want with it without needing to ask for permission.

# ========== INSTRUCTIONS ==========
# This add-on does not change anything until you edit it.
#
# Between the square brackets at the far left, you may insert any number of
# lines, each of which specifies a command to be run on your system. When Anki
# goes to generate LaTeX images, it will run each command in sequence. At the
# end of each line, after the closing square bracket, there should be a comma,
# except on the final command.
#
# Each command must be enclosed in square brackets and may contain any number
# of quoted, comma-separated arguments, the first being the command to run and
# the remainder being command-line arguments.
#
# Please see the default command set for an example. If you are having trouble
# configuring this add-on, you may ask on the add-ons forum.
#
# NOTE: If you are using this add-on on Windows, you must use double
# backslashes (\\) in any paths you include: "C:\\Windows", not "C:\Windows".
# ==================================

#newLaTeX = \
#[
#    ["latex", "-interaction=nonstopmode", "tmp.tex"],
#    ["dvipng", "-D", "200", "-T", "tight", "tmp.dvi", "-o", "tmp.png"]
#]

# TikZ compliant setting
newLaTeX = \
[
  ["pdflatex", "-interaction=nonstopmode", "--shell-escape", "tmp.tex"]
]

# make the changes
import anki.latex
anki.latex.latexCmds = newLaTeX
```

Latex code :

```
\providecommand{\pgfsyspdfmark}[3]{}
\documentclass[convert={convertexe={convert}},border=2]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath, amsfonts, mathrsfs}
\usepackage[paperwidth=5in, paperheight=100in]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{pgf, tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\pagestyle{empty}
\setlength{\parindent}{0in}
\begin{document}

\ce{{{c1::H3O}}+}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw (0, 0) -- (4, 0) -- (4, 4) -- (0, 4) -- (0, 0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Remove at least the line loading the `geometry` package. It doesn't make sense with the `standalone` class, but influences the output. With this line, the page is empty, without it I get the string `c1::H30`^`+` followed by a square, which one would expect from the code. Btw, what *is* the expected output?

Comment: What is the purpose of `\ce{{{c1::H3O}}+}`? It doesn't look like the `mhchem` package is able to handle it, in contrast to `\ce{H3O+}`.

Comment: {{c1::  }} Allow to hide a note with Anik, but he has no consequence to the latex in that case. Advice which I followed was for an user of Windows, but me I work with Mac. I had to make a mistake in some orders which are not compatible with Mac. I delete geometry but it still does not work. Thank for your help.

Comment: I have added an answer which describes how I get it running under Linux/Ubuntu 16.04. My hope is that it will also work under MacOs. If you still have probems, we have to check the files in Anki's temporary directory (and I have to grab my son's Mac).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The original problem was caused by a buggy converter from pdf to png. It was first solved by downgrading from `imagemagick` 7.0.x to `imagemagick` 6.9.x and then by switching to `sips`. Below I describe how to setup Anki for use with pdflatex and `imagemagick`/`sips`.

## How to set up Anki for pdflatex (as required by tikz and other packages)

The setup consists of adding

- a suitable preamble and
- a corresponding add-on (python script) for converting TeX code to png pictures.

We first present two variants with the corresponding code fragments, and then explain where to put these fragments in Anki.

### Variant 1 (recommended): `standalone` class, png conversion with `imagemagick` or `sips`

The `standalone` class is able to crop/trim the image itself and therefore can be used with converters that can't do it (like `sips`).

Preamble:

```
\documentclass[12pt,border=1mm,varwidth=3in]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\begin{document}
```

Modify the value `3in` for the maximal width to be smaller or greater.

Anki add-on for pdf/png conversion using `convert` from the `imagemagick` tools; call it e.g. `pdflatex-convert.py`:

```
newLaTeX = \
[
    ["pdflatex", "-interaction=nonstopmode", "tmp.tex"],
    ["convert", "-density", "200", "-trim", "tmp.pdf", "tmp.png"]
]
import anki.latex
anki.latex.latexCmds = newLaTeX
```

Alternatively, under MacOS you can use the pre-installed tool `sips` (scriptable image processing system) with the following script `pdflatex-sips.py`:

```
newLaTeX = \
[
    ["pdflatex", "-interaction=nonstopmode", "tmp.tex"],
    ["sips", "-s", "format", "png", "tmp.pdf", "--out", "tmp.png"]
]
import anki.latex
anki.latex.latexCmds = newLaTeX
```

### Variant 2: `article` class, png conversion with `imagemagick`

This preamble is close to Anki's default, hence it probably works with all existing notes. It is less robust than the preamble using `standalone`. E.g., if a box (like an included picture) is to wide for the page, it may be moved to a second page; but then the conversion to `png` will fail.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[text={3in,5in}]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\pagestyle{empty}
\setlength{\parindent}{0in}
\begin{document}
```

As Anki add-on for pdf/png conversion use `pdflatex-convert.py` from above. `pdflatex-sips` will not work since neither the `article` class nor `sips` will trim the picture.

**Remarks.** If you want to use macros from specific packages, you have to add the corresponding `\usepackage` commands to the preambles above. E.g., you may additionally need `\usepackage{tikz}` for pictures. You don't have to collect all packages that you have ever used or will ever use in a single preamble; define instead several types of notes with different preambles, e.g. one for pictures and one for texts.

The Anki add-ons presented above are variants of `Edit_LaTeX_build_process.py` as offered at the Anki website, and *replace* the latter.

### How to install the Anki add-on

Start Anki and select `Tools` | `Add-ons` | `Open Add-ons Folder...`. Copy the Python script (the `py`-file from above) into this folder. Move any other script that modifies Anki's LaTeX handling, like `Edit_LaTeX_build_process.py` and its compiled version `Edit_LaTeX_build_process.pyc`, out of the way, e.g. by moving them into an sub-folder `old`.

After that you have to restart Anki.

### How to install the preamble

Start Anki, select `Tools` | `Manage Note Types` | your note type using latex | `Options`, and copy the preamble into this window.

[image]

### Example

Paste the code `[latex]{{c1::\ce{H3O+} }}\begin{tikzpicture}\draw (0,0) -- (4,0) -- (4,4) -- (0,4) -- (0,0);\end{tikzpicture}[/latex]` into a note of type `cloze` that uses one of the preambles above with the additional packages `tikz` and `mhchem`.

[image]

Anki generates the following two cards with a chemical formula and a simple tikz picture.

[image] [image]

Comment: Thanks for your help. I changed my file as described but I unfortunately still a mistake.


I try another method but I have a problem with the command "convert". Yet she walks into the terminal.
2ème méthod :

newLaTeX = \
[
    ["pdflatex", "-interaction=nonstopmode", "tmp.tex"],
    ["convert", "-trim", "-density", "300", "tmp.pdf", "tmp.png"]
]
(With this method all files are created except tmp.png)

Comment: bug report:

IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'/var/folders/v1/psh6j3c139x1wkj2k38_77v40000gn/T/anki_temp/tmp.png'

Comment: @tym007 Do you have `imagemagick` installed on your computer? On the command line, enter `which convert`. If it says something like `/usr/bin/convert`, go to Anki's tmp directory and execute `convert -density 300 tmp.pdf tmp.png` manually. View the pdf and the png files; do they look ok?

Comment: To be more precise in the error that gave me in the first method. ! Extra }, or forgotten Error executing pdflatex..........
...................
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on tmp.log.
system returned with code 256
 (./tmp.aux)sh: convert: command not found
system returned with code 32512


Class standalone Warning: Conversion unsuccessful!
(standalone)              There might be something wrong with your
(standalone)              conversation software or the file permissions!

Comment: oops, when I execute convert -density 300 tmp.pdf tmp.png I have a  error "Abort trap: 6"

Comment: In the first method, have a look at `tmp.log` to find out where this `Extra }` error comes from. If you run `pdflatex` manually on `tmp.tex`, do you get an error, or does the resulting `tmp.pdf` look as it should?

Comment: On the imagemagick website there is the advice to upgrade to the newest imagemagick version in case of `trap: 6`, as this error indicates images that corrupt memory, and the newer the version of imagemagick is, the more memory problems have been fixed. I have version 6.8.9 installed, but the newest one seems to be 7.0.3. What does `convert -version` say?

Comment: @tym007 Does `tmp.tex` compile without errors, manually? If not, add it temporarily to your posting. If yes, check whether the pdf looks ok, and send it to the imagemagick people; in a discussion they promised to fix trap 6 memory problems within a few days.

Comment: @tym007 So the problem is that `convert` from the `imagemagick` suite fails to convert a pdf- to a png-file with a trap 6 error, right? You can report it as a bug to the imagemagick project, and/or try to use `sips`. This is a conversion tool under MacOS that might work as well. See e.g. ["Converting Image File Formats with the Command Line & sips"](http://osxdaily.com/2013/01/11/converting-image-file-formats-with-the-command-line-sips/).

Comment: @tym007 I have added a note about how to use `sips`, after checking that it really works.

Comment: Hi, I tested three solution. She walks all, but I can not add this code without its plant. It only works with the original Add-on \begin{easylist}
& Main item~:
&& Sub item.
&& Another sub item.
\end{easylist}  One idea is to solve the problem?

Comment: For the moment I manually change between the two add-on when I need to use tikz. Once the convertion is made in the image remains the media collection Anki. But there must be a Conditional stucture that could meet both.

Comment: @tym007 I think I've found a solution, see both variants above (I've rewritten my answer once more). Please test the methods with your notes and let me know if you encounter problems.

Comment: Actually this function with both methods, whether with "itemize" or "minipage. It does not work with the troix method that has been removed.
`["pdflatex", "-interaction=nonstopmode", "-shell-escape", "tmp.tex"], `
We must go "itemize" or "minipage" in the setting of the card because if you write next, anki puts side by side images. Thanks

Comment: @tym007 I've just modified the `standalone` approach: When one adds the `varwidth` option, also your easylist example works. Do I understand you correctly that at the moment everything works? Or is there still a problem? (I didn't completely understand whether your remark on itemize, minipage, and side-by-side images describes a problem or is just an explanation.)

Comment: it works with "tikz", "mhchem" too. My problem is solved.

Comment: Hello, do you know if it's possible to put an image in an Anki card with latex code. I made several test, but without success. thank you

Comment: @tym007 Yes, it is possible. Add `\usepackage{graphicx}` to the preamble, if it is not yet loaded by some other package (like `pgfplots`). Then `[latex]\includegraphics{myfile.png}[/latex]` should load the image. Some things may go wrong, though. Inspect tmp.tex and tmp.log, if it fails. E.g., if the image is too wide, use `\includegraphics[width=3cm]{...}`. If the filename or path contains special characters, you may need `\string` or `\detokenize`, see [How to use tilde or space in includepdf filename?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34919/110998).

Comment: @tym007 As a first test, use \includegraphics{example-image-a}. if you have a current TeXLive, then this image is on the search path. If this works, you know that any failures with your own images are due to either "image not found", "image too wide", or "strange characters in file name".

Comment: @tym007 If the image is too big, then the preamble with the `article` class will generate a pdf with two pages, and the conversion to `png` fails (to be solved with `[width=...]`). The preamble with `standalone` will just cut the image, but not fail.

Comment: In fact. For "\ usepackage {graphicx}" walking. We must put the image in the same file as the .tex. But on Anki, I do not know where to put it can be used with this function. An idea?

Comment: @tym007 Either give the full path, like `\includegraphics{/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mwe/example-image-a.jpg}`, or set the `\graphicspath`, or set the `TEXINPUTS` variable to include the directory with the images. If the file name or path includes spaces or special characters, see e.g. the answers to [How to include graphics with spaces in their path?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8422/110998). For infos on `\graphicspath`, see the [WikiBook on LaTeX/Importing Graphics](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Importing_Graphics).

Comment: J'ai essayer avec ce code, mais cela ne marche pas. '\includegraphics{/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/late‌​x/mwe/td.jpg}'

Comment: I try with this code, but it does not. '\includegraphics{/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/lat‌​e‌​x/mwe/td.jpg}'

Comment: @tym007 How does `tmp.tex` look like? What does `tmp.log` say? What happens when you compile `tmp.tex` yourself? Does the image /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/lat‌​‌​ex/mwe/td.jpg really exist on your system? It doesn't on my system ... If `td.jpg` is your image, you have to use the path of this file instead of /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist...

Comment: Hello. I want my text does not exceed the edge of the screen automatically. Currently I use \\ at the end of each line. advise on? thank you

Comment: @tym007 I'm not completely sure that I understand your problem. If the problem is that the page is too wide: Try `\documentclass[12pt,border=1mm,varwidth=5cm]{standalone}` to set a maximum width of 5cm (change as needed).

Comment: when I use "paragraph" without configuration used for Anki ("varwidth ......"), I can write my text without exceeds the side of the pdf document. With the configuration Anki Latex, I have to use "\\" to prevent it exceeds the pdf document.

Comment: [link]<a href="http://zupimages.net/viewer.php?id=16/42/54ac.png"><img src="http://zupimages.net/up/16/42/54ac.png" alt="" /></a> [link] [link]<a href="http://zupimages.net/viewer.php?id=16/42/2w15.png"><img src="http://zupimages.net/up/16/42/2w15.png" alt="" /></a> [link]

Comment: http://www.zupimages.net/viewer.php?id=16/42/54ac.png

Comment: http://www.zupimages.net/viewer.php?id=16/42/2w15.png

Comment: @tym007 Use the option `varwidth=3in` for the `standalone` class (see also the updated answer above). Without giving an explicit width, the standard textwidth will be used. But in both cases I can't really reproduce your problem. If you can't solve the problem, please ask a new question (there are already too many comments) and add the code (preamble as well as document body) to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Good morning.

Already, thanks to Gernot to have helped me.

To conclude, the version of `convert` of `ImageMagick` `7.0.1` did not walk.

I therefore abolished the version of ImageMagick that I had installed with Mac port.

`sudo port uninstall imagemagick`

Then, I downloaded with `brew` another version of `ImageMagick`. `(6.9.6-0)`

`brew instal imagemagick`

I did not supplement installation procedure as to point out on this [site](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php), not to change the version of ImageMagick.

```
Create (or choose) a directory to install the package into and change to that directory, for example:

cd $HOME
Next, extract the contents of the package. For example:

tar xvzf ImageMagick-x86_64-apple-darwin15.2.0.tar.gz
Set the MAGICK_HOME environment variable to the path where you extracted the ImageMagick files. For example:

 export MAGICK_HOME="$HOME/ImageMagick-7.0.3"
If the bin subdirectory of the extracted package is not already in your executable search path, add it to your PATH environment variable. For example:

export PATH="$MAGICK_HOME/bin:$PATH"
Set the DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable:

export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="$MAGICK_HOME/lib/"
Finally, to verify ImageMagick is working properly, type the following on the command line:

magick logo: logo.gif
identify logo.gif
display logo.gif
Note, the display program requires the X11 server available on your Mac OS X installation DVD. Once that is installed, you will also need to export DISPLAY=:0.
```

I then tested by letting the same regulatings give by Gernot and all these pasts correctly.

No error all my files are generated.

Thank you still to have helped me.