# insert MAPLE algorithm to LaTeX

Tags: graphics, code

I am writing my dissertation through LaTeX, and I want to insert the code from MAPLE, it is about 2 pages and I am not sure how to include the algorithm, do you have any idea how am I going to do it?

Answer (score 4):

Maple (I assume you are talking about http://www.maplesoft.com/) has a built in style for including Maple code to the LaTeX environment.

What you do is simply locate you installation directory:

```
~/apps/maple15/
```

is my installation directory. If you are on a Windows machine it will be something like:

```
C:\Program Files\MapleSoft\Maple15
```

Within a folder named `etc` is located. In that style files and definitions used for Maple is located, you should see the following files:

```
maple2e.sty   
mapleenv.sty    
maplestd2e.sty  
mapletab.sty
mapleenv.def
mapleplots.sty
maplestyle.sty  
mapleutil.sty
```

if you use the built in Maple to LaTeX exporter you simply need to add these style files and definitions to your path.

I.e. copy them to your TeX file and compile.

I have attached a small output of an as-is output:

[image]

It has the last section folded in.

Comment: thank's but I have a problem with the graphs,I can't see them into latex, and last how am I going to connect my dissertation file with   the file that has the maple code

Comment: @Vangelis the graphs are in exported in eps format. So change them to whatever format you use. Then simply strip the Maple TeX file from the header and include it in your dissertation. Just remember to add the preamble from the Maple output to your dissertation as well. If in doubt please provide a full minimal example in your question.

Comment: @zeroth I have been trying to change the MapleFont size without success. Do you know how to achieve that?

Comment: @pluton look in the style files... for direct manipulation. Else you enclose the environments in a block which reduces the size of the font. Search around for having several default font sizes.

Comment: alright. Strangely, they define the \MapleSize and \MapleFont commands that are never used in the .sty files.

Comment: I have followed the steps above: chuck all the Maple files into the same directory and then for the images I followed " change them to whatever format you use" by using the `epstopdf` package. But... it doesn't work.

Comment: @User17670 you need to give me more information. What does the log information tell you?

Comment: @zeroth I get an overfull hbox but that's it. The file compiles and it shows the text in the document quite nicely. However, for the figure I have in my maple file, it just has the caption, with no actual plot.

Comment: @User17670 Check where in the file the `includegraphics` is and make sure that it refers to the correct file. Make sure that the file ending is correct (you could try and add/remove it).

Comment: @zeroth There is no `includegraphics` line in the code. Should there be? All I did was this: clicked File>Export>LaTeX.

Comment: @User17670 look for `\mapleplot{figurename.eps}` and change that to `\mapleplot{figurename}`, then `pdflatex` will automatically grab the PDF version of the file. Remember that you have to have runned `eps2pdf` on _figurename.eps_ before.

Comment: I didn't remove the .eps but, but I did remove the spaces from the file name and add the `graphicx` package. I don't know which of these fixed it. This is what I hate about LaTeX.

Comment: @User17670 It was the space, please see: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8422/how-to-include-graphics-with-spaces-in-their-path

Comment: When I export maple documents, they only show [the output of the commands](https://www.mapleprimes.com/DocumentFiles/224631_question/Applying_the_taylor_series_method_to_the_L1_model.pdf) not [the commands themselves](https://www.mapleprimes.com/view.aspx?sf=224631_question/Applying_the_taylor_series_method_to_the_L1_model.mw). How do i fix this?