# How to use an exported Maple transcript in LaTeX

Tags: texmaker, maple2e

I'm using Texmaker, TeX Live and Mac OS Mavericks.

When I run Texmaker on the exported Maple transcript it comes up with multiple errors.

Where do I find the packages required to make it work and how do I install them?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Can you post an example of the code produced by Maple, it is impossible to say what is missing without more information.

Comment: Related http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/68060/14757

Comment: The first error that occurred was "LaTeX Error: File `maplestd2e.sty' not found." I fixed this by downloading and installing it. But then it came up with "LaTeX Error: File 'mapleenv.def' not found."

Comment: @rossi_182, see the link I posted.

Comment: Yes I've seen this, it tells you where the files are located on a Windows machine. Where do I find these on a Mac?

Comment: http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/maple

Comment: @Sigur Where are mapleenv.def etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve it by first reformatting my Maple document so it was all in Maple input.

I then found the required packages by googling them, copying the text into a text editor and saving them as their name in the directory my tex file is in.

So for example for `mapleenv.def`, I googled it to find this http://users.wfu.edu/wickersg/latex/maple/mapleenv.def, I copied this text, pasted it into a text editor and saved it as `mapleenv.def` in the directory of my tex file.

To make my graphs work I put `\usepackage{graphicx}` at the beginning of the document.

Answer (score 0):

Обратите внимание, что при экспорте из Maple в .tex отсутствует:
% устанавливаем русшрифт
\usepackage[cp1251]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}

Comment: This is an English-speaking website so please write your answer in English.