# How do I put a line break in for a line of Maple input that is too long?

Tags: texmaker, maple2e

I've exported a Maple worksheet to LaTeX. The main problem is the Maple input is too long for one line, how do I put in line breaks?

This is the code I want to fix,

```
\begin{mapleinput}
\mapleinline{active}{1d}{eq1 := diff(theta[1](t), `$`(t, 2))+(1+Delta)*sin(theta[1](t))+ mu*((theta[1](t)/theta[0])\symbol{94}2-1)*(diff(theta[1](t), t))-beta*cos(theta[1](t))*(diff(sin(theta[1](t))+sin(theta[2](t)), `$`(t, 2))) = 0;}{}
\end{mapleinput}
```

Currently it does this.[image]
You can see how it needs a line break.

Comment: It seems like [MapleSoft](http://www.maplesoft.com/) doesn't provide their LaTeX style files somewhere online - it is included with the distribution of the software. It would be difficult to address this issue without those files. A list of these files is discussed in [insert MAPLE algorithm to LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/68060/5764).

Comment: It seems that a line break in input corresponds to a line break in output.

Comment: @egreg It starts a new line of input. This is not what I am looking for. Thanks for the help none the less.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define

```
\newcommand{\maplebreak}{\hfill\break}
```

and place `\maplebreak` at appropriate spots in the line.

I also found better to use a smaller font size, as the lines are too filled.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[noplots]{maplestd2e}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\pretocmd\mapleinput{\par\small}{}{} % print the environment at a smaller size
\newcommand\maplebreak{\hfill\break} % where to break lines

\begin{document}
\begin{mapleinput}
\mapleinline{active}{1d}{eq1 := diff(theta[1](t), `$`(t, 2))+(1+Delta)*sin(theta[1](t))+\maplebreak mu*((theta[1](t)/theta[0])\symbol{94}2-1)*(diff(theta[1](t), t))-\maplebreak beta*cos(theta[1](t))*(diff(sin(theta[1](t))+sin(theta[2](t)),\maplebreak `$`(t, 2))) = 0;}{}
\end{mapleinput}
\end{document}
```

[image]