# How to insert pdf (as a graphic file) in LaTeX

Tags: graphics, errors, pdf

I am trying to insert some ready image-pdf files to my LaTeX code.

(I use pdfLaTeX and my distributor is TeXnicCenter.)

But I will get this error:

```
Package pdftex.def Error: File 'fig1.pdf' not found.
```

I already tried putting `fig1` not `fig1.pdf`, having both `.pdf` and `.eps` files in the given directory, but nothing changed.

My code is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt, reqno]{amsbook}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{F:/(some path here...)/pdfs/}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.eps}



\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htb]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{fig1.pdf}
\caption{Digraph.}
\label{fig:digraph}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Try to save the figure file at the same folder as your `tex` file just to see if the problem is with the path.

Comment: If you have spaces (or other special characters) in the path, or file name, then you should try to put those in quotes.

Comment: And [welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).

Comment: Have you tried the solutions at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8422/how-to-include-graphics-with-spaces-in-their-path?

Comment: graphicspath takes a list of directories each in `{}` so you need an additional `{}` but it's simpler and your document is more portable if you do not use graphicspath at all and just put the files in the current directory