# Duplicate captions problem with figure

Tags: graphics, floats, captions

I am a beginner in LaTeX. I used the LaTeX example to insert a figure in my thesis. Here is the code:

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figs/#####.jpg}
\vspace{0in}
\caption{#####}
\end{figure}
```

I think the code should only generate one caption below the figure.

However, I got two captions with my figure. The form is like:

> #####.jpg
>
> (The figure itself looks fine)
>
> Fig1.1 #####

Anyone had this problem in the past? How could I get rid of the top #####.jpg?

Comment: Hi, welcome to TeX.SX. Do you by any chance have any spaces in the filename of the image? (See e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84378/xelatex-includegraphics-with-a-png-file-shows-filename-in-output-how-do-i-hi)

Comment: Have you tried using `\usepackage{grffile}`?

Comment: Can you compile your question into a minimal working example? The "#1" as parameter to the "\caption" command suggests that you are showing the definition of a macro, but the rest of the question does not indicate this.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @MarioS.E. I tried just now, but it gave me an error message:　File "griffile.sty" not found. \ usepackage

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thanks! I tried that and it worked! Is there any way to omit the spaces in the filename of the figure? I used newcommand for inserting figure, and thinking to use #1 for both figure filename and caption name, so I only need to type it once instead of twice.

Comment: You tried what? Note that the package Mario mentioned is called `grffile`, not `griffile`.