# Part of the file name of my image is printed in the document, twice

Tags: graphics, external-files

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to include graphics with spaces in their path?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8422/how-to-include-graphics-with-spaces-in-their-path)

When I add a piece of code of figure insertion to the context I'm faced with a problem: a number of irrelevant words appear.

Code:

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{C:/Thesis/Latex/thesis_1(1)/Pictures/study area.jpg}
        \rule{35em}{0.3pt}
    \caption{The Grand St. Bernard wireless sensor network deployment (a) the coordinates of nodes according to the Swiss coordinate system (b) the distribution of the nodes in the study site \citep{r33}}
    \label{fig:study area}
\end{figure}
```

Problem:

[image: Error which is presented by sign]

Comment: it looks as if this has something to do with the space in the file name (but others know more about this).  what i really wanted to do is suggest that you put a "slash space" (`\ `) after "St." so that the space there isn't so large.

Comment: rename your file so that it does not include white spaces, e.g. `study_area.jpg`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Earlier you were not allowed to have spaces in a file name but now you can (see e.g. [this page](http://wiki.lyx.org/LaTeX/FilesWithSpecialChars) for more details). Obviously you still get some unwanted results. A good solution is to avoid spaces in filenames altogether and use hyphens or underscore characters instead.