# Referencing bib files with spaces in the filename

Tags: biblatex, texlive, paths

I am using a Mac with TeX Live and Mendeley for automatically generating `.bib` files, some of which have spaces in the file names. I would like to know how to reference such files from LaTeX as using `""` or `\` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Does this help? [How to include graphics with spaces in their path?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8422)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to include graphics with spaces in their path?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8422/how-to-include-graphics-with-spaces-in-their-path)

Comment: I don't see that this is a duplicate.  It is the bibtex stage that chokes on the space in the filename.

Answer (score 5):

This depends on which backend you are using.

If the backend is `bibtex` then no spaces are allowed in the filename (and there are other restrictions such as the length of the name must not be more than 40 characters). LaTeX will happily write the file name to the `.aux` file, but `bibtex` will complain when it reads the resulting `\bibdata` command.

If you use `biber` as the backend, which is now the standard for `biblatex` then this restriction has been removed, you just use `\addbibresource` as standard:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{file with spaces.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

If `file with spaces.bib` contains

```
@Article{Auth,
  author =   {Author},
  title =    {Title},
  journal =  {Jour.},
  year =     2000
}
```

then you get

[image: Sample output]

after running through `pdflatex`, `biber`, `pdflatex`.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I use bibtex as my backend. I have not previously tried using biber for references.