# How to make space recognized in .bib filename when setting bibliography?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I have a .bib file called "A B C.bib" which is assigned to "A B C.tex". When I run .tex file and then .bib file I get the following error:

```
 White space in argument---line 18 of file A B C.aux
 : \bibdata{'A
 :             B C'}
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
```

Comment: I don't think BibTeX supports files with spaces in their names. The control about spaces in the file name is built in BibTeX.

Comment: @egreg Sorry but I didn't understand your response. What do you mean that control about spaces is built in BibTeX??

Comment: + What should I do?

Comment: That error message is issued by BibTeX, which *doesn't* accept file names with a space as legal `.bib` files. What can you do? Rename your `.bib` file omitting the spaces.

Comment: Then bibTeX looks for the .aux file with the same name as .bib which means I have to change the name of .tex file as well!

Comment: BibTeX inputs the `.aux` file you tell it to, which usually isn't the same name as the `.bib` file. If your TeX file is called `naji.tex` the `.bib` file can be anything, as long as it hasn't spaces in its name.

Comment: I didn't know that. My .bib files has only reference information. Can I ask you what is the command to change the default which looks for .aux file with the same name?

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/102258/15925

Answer (score 11, accepted):

BibTeX doesn't accept spaces in the name of the bibliography file it inputs. So a file named `A B C.bib` is rejected.

It's by no means necessary that the `.bib` file has the same name as the LaTeX file; to the contrary, many people organize their big bibliography file and call that one for all their papers.

Example. The following is the file `naji.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\cite{x} \cite{y}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{najibibdatabase}

\end{document}
```

You process it by saying

```
pdflatex naji
bibtex naji
pdflatex naji
pdflatex naji
```

and it's BibTeX's job to read from `naji.aux` the line

```
\bibdata{najibibdatabase}
```

so it can open for reading the file `najibibdatabase` and extract from it the entries corresponding to the `x` and `y` keys.

There's no requirement that the argument to `\bibliography` is the same name as the main TeX file where it's given.

In any case it's best to avoid spaces in file names for all TeX-related documents.

Comment: I am actually doing it in texshop in Mac. I also did the same as you wrote but then when I run bibTeX(press bibTeX button in TeXshop) I get the following error:
I couldn't open file name `Najibib.aux'

Comment: I set the name of the tex as Naji.tex and the bib as Najibib.bib

Comment: @Naji: in which window are you hitting the button? It should be the window with the tex file, not the bib file.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang I first hit the LaTeX button on .tex file, then press the bibTeX button on .bib file which I used to do for any other document(without spaces) but now I have this trouble when .bib and .tex does not have the same name!

Comment: @Naji You don't have to open the `.bib` file in TeXShop. Just choose "BibTeX" from the drop down menu and launch Command-T.

Answer (score 2):

If you are working on a mac or linux, you can use a symbolic link to your .bib file. At the command line, type `ln -s <target> bib.bib` to create a symbolic link between `bib.bib` and your actual .bib file. You can now use `\bibliography{bib}` in the .tex file.

Comment: The thing is I am not using Terminal to TeX my files, I use TeXshop itself.

Comment: @Naji: That's not really a problem, you only need the terminal to create the link once.

Comment: But then I have to keep doing this link for every new tex file, right? :D

Comment: @Naji actually, no - you can copy the symbolic link to a new location once you've made it.

Comment: Windows also supports symbolic links with `mklink <link> <target>`. Note that the order of arguments is reversed vs `ln -s`