# arara: problem with spaces in the name of .tex files?

Tags: auxiliary-files, naming, arara

I know that there is a [problem with spaces in the name of `.bib` files](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112606/how-to-make-space-recognized-in-bib-filename-when-setting-bibliography). Nonetheless, the following MWE compiles perfectly fine if one does the normal `latex` -> `bibtex` -> `latex` -> `latex` compilation sequence by hand, *regardless of whether there are spaces in the name of the **`.tex`** file*.

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: bibtex
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}

\citet{friederici1993}

\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{master}

\end{document}
```

However, as soon as one tries to compile this MWE with `arara` and ***if** there are spaces in the name of the **`.tex`** file*, it will **not** work. It seems to be a problem with reading from the `.aux` file, as per the error message:

> ```
> Running BibTeX... 
>
> I couldn't open file name `"2014-01-24 Friederici et al 1993 Presentation.aux".aux'
> FAILURE
> ```

Is there are a workaround, or is this unavoidable? Does one *have* to use file names without spaces for **`.tex`** files if one is using `arara` to compile?

Comment: As far as i know, arara does not support spaces in filenames for good reasons. That's a feature, not a bug. Remove the spaces, and i think everything is going to be fine. http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/13311129#13311129

Comment: @Johannes_B it does indeed work after the spaces are removed. I was just curious if there is a way to retain spaces in `.tex` file names when using `arara`. I don't necessarily know why it would be a feature, but I also don't know that much about file naming schemes, file structures, *etc.*, so it's perhaps no surprise that I can't think up a reason why it would be considered a feature. Could you clarify why it would be a feature?

Comment: @Johannes_B Hahah, thanks for link! `:)`

Comment: If you look at the date: It was just yesterday, read a bit and i think your question will be answered. You can take a look at the chat log from when your question was posted as well `;-)`

Comment: @Johannes_B if you want to turn this into an answer, I'd be happy to accept it. If you do, you should mention that I deserve no sympathy. `:)` I thought that was pretty entertaining.

Comment: Related [Naming LaTeX files: best practice?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12174/15717) also see [examples of filenames](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12176/15717)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

<sup>**First of all, an interesting remark:** it's quite surprising and amusing that this fact went unnoticed for virtually every single release of `arara`. I blame Nicola, of course: once she found this major issue, apparently the universe captured an unbalanced force and decided to go ballistic. `:)`</sup>

<sup>As retaliation, Nicola is now part of the official `arara` team. ♥</sup>

This is clearly a bug and major issue of the current version of `arara` (`3.0` as the time of writing). To be more precise, the culprit is actually one of the libraries `arara` relies on, and not the tool itself. If we check `arara.log` (via `--log`), we can check that the command is being correctly expanded, say

```
pdflatex "file with spaces.tex"
```

Rules are actually written with that concern in mind, but I really had no idea the underlying code would fail me. `:)` Interestingly enough, the above call works. So, for some commands, like `pdflatex`, the execution works; for others, like `makeindex`, `makeglossaries` (the one that made Nicola spot <strike>[the looney](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z_Nq3xuHkgE)</strike> the issue) and `bibtex`, execution falls flat on its face.

I'm studying a way to fix this, and apparently the folks at Apache are [aware of the bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/EXEC-54) in their execution library, but there's no solution so far that doesn't involve a lot of hacking. I know this is quite frustrating, and the only workaround is to, well, avoid spaces in filenames. `:)`

Sorry for the trouble. I'm now aware of the problem and will look forward to a solution.

Comment: Oh oooooooooooooooooooh! :-) Don't be sad, nothing is perfect and we always learn from short falls. :-)

Comment: @azetina: one man's bug is another man's feature. `:)`

Comment: That was what I was trying to say :-) Shame on myself. By the way thanks for a wonderful contribution (`arara`). It is very helpful.

Comment: @azetina: `♥` We already have a solution for this issue: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/41?m=13314557#13314557 `:)`