# How to add graphics in LaTeX

Tags: graphics

How can we define the path if our file is at another place?

I got this one that in preamble, we will write

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
```

Then for uploading graphics we will use

```
\includegraphics{File.extension}
```

But what in case if file is at another place, how will I give the path to it, how will I center it and how can I add text to it?

Comment: That’s in no way related to TeXnicCenter, therefore I made an edit to the title.

Comment: Related (no duplicate): [How to include graphics with spaces in their path?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8422/how-to-include-graphics-with-spaces-in-their-path).

Answer (score 8):

For the sake of synchronizing our mind, lets assume:

- the main input file is in a folder named `Current` (for example),
- the folder `Current` is in a folder named  `Parent`,
- a folder named `diagrams` containing diagrams is also in the folder `Parent`,
- a folder named `photos` containing photos is in the folder `Current`.

By using `\graphicspath` you can declare the paths to the photos and diagrams you want to refer in you main input file. Each path must be enclosed in `{}` and must be ended with `/`.

The remaining should be clear.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{photos/},{../diagrams/}}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{filename}% no need to specify the file extension
\caption{Karl's students }
\label{fig:Karlsstudents}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

General advice: place all graphics file in a 'pictures' subdirectory directly under your path. You can then load the files using

`\includegraphics{./pictures/File.extension}`

Using the Dot-Notation you can also use directories above. The following line would go one directory level up (from the directory where your TeX file is), would then go to the 'myfiles/pictures' directory and use 'File.extension'

`\includegraphics{../myfiles/pictures/File.extension}`

I would not recommend you to separate the TeX files and the graphics files completely. Having everything together makes moving the document directory much easier.

Comment: If you want to go three levels up, how do you do: `../../..` or `....`? I don't remember where, but I have seen both ways of doing it, and just don't know which one does TeX uses.

Comment: '../../..' is correct.

Comment: Somehow, I got it by doing one thing, defining path name and then giving file name and its extension. Anyways, Thank you very much..

Answer (score 3):

I'm using the current setup for figures:

```
\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width = 0.8\textwidth]{path/figurefile}
    \caption{Somecaption \label{fig:somelabel}}
\end{figure}
```

It is also possible to specify `\graphicspath{path}` in the preamble such that you can omit `path/` in `includegraphics`. LaTeX will then search for `figurefile` in `path`, but not subfolders of `path`, them you will have to specify in `\includegraphics`.

Comment: Yeah, I got it.