# Inserting a pdf plot into Latex

Tags: graphics, pdftex

I'm trying to inset a pdf plot into my Latex document. I've looked up various solutions on this site to similar problems, but none seem to work. I am very new to Latex so excuse me for the poor question.

The PDF plot I want to download is in my downloads folder on my computer. I tried using

```
\usepackage{pdfpages}
```

followed by

```
\includepdf[pages=-,pagecommand={},width=\textwidth]{Rplot.pdf}
```

But it says it cannot find the file.

Comment: It sounds like you probably want to use `\usepackage{graphicx}` and `\includegraphics{Rplot}`, not `pdfpages`. Just like `\includepdf` though, this requires that `Rplot.pdf` is in the same folder as your `.tex` file.

Comment: @Bernard You mean `\graphicspath{ {/path/to/downloadfolder/} }`?  Leonhard, see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107160/how-to-add-graphics-in-latex

Comment: Use `\graphicspath{{/path/to/downloadfolder/}}` (don't forget the double braces) in your preamble, and `\includegraphics{Rplot}` where you want it in the body of the document. Needless the mention the extension, unless you have other graphic files withe same name and another extension.

Comment: I managed to get it working by moving the files to my Documents folder!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the op solved it himself (see last comment)