# How to exclude the picture's path?

Tags: diagrams

I imported a picture and LaTeX created pdf well. The problem is the path (like `C:/users/file_name/....jpg`) is above the picture in the pdf file. How can I exclude that?

Comment: Is the picture path _in_ the pdf which you include? If so this has been answered, orther wise you probably have the path written twice.

Comment: Can you show us the code you used to import the picture? Also you could show us a screen shot how the picture looks in the pdf. Just upload your screenshot and delete the leading `!`. A user with more rep can activate the image for you.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: It's not clear either what is happening (give an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), and also the picture Kurt asked for), or what you want instead.  Do you want the path to be shown, but below rather than above the graphic?

Answer (score 1):

Usually this is caused by spaces in the file name or by other special characters that usually need to be escaped in LaTeX. An probably easy fix is to change your filenames or to load the `\usepackage[space]{grffile}` package as explained [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8422/how-to-include-graphics-with-spaces-in-their-path/8426#8426).

Note that if your files are in the project folder with you main tex file or in a sub folder of you project folder it is not necessary to give the whole path including drive letter etc..

Project folder

L->Main.tex

L-> picture.png

`\includegraphics{picture}`

or

Project folder

L->Main.tex

L-> Figures/picture.png

`\includegraphics{Figures/picture}`

will work.