# Problem with importing image

Tags: graphics, sharelatex

I added a png image named MVC Unit 2 Question 1 Graph 1 to the directory, but I am not able to add the image to Latex. I am currently using online Share LaTeX, which I believe is pdflatex.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\includegraphics{MVC_Unit_2_Question_1_Graph_1}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I have added the tag to reflect that this question is more about writelatex than about graphics, as the MWE illustrates. +1 for the MWE.

Comment: Make sure your image's filename and the argument of `\includegraphics` are _exactly_ the same. Pay attention to capitals, spaces vs underscores, extension, etc.

Comment: I fixed it somehow by changing my file names to having no space. Thus, my file name became MVCUnit2Question1Graph1. However, how come it does not work when I have space between?

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8422/how-to-include-graphics-with-spaces-in-their-path