# Multiple images to PDF using pdflatex

Tags: graphics, pdftex

For a long time I used to losslessly convert muliple PNGs to a single PDF using the following template:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[margin=0pt]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\enlargethispage*{0cm}
%
%
\centering{
\includegraphics[width=.99\paperwidth,totalheight=.99\paperheight,keepaspectratio]{img1.png}
\clearpage
\includegraphics[width=.99\paperwidth,totalheight=.99\paperheight,keepaspectratio]{img2.png}
\clearpage
}
\end{document}
```

Lately, I've been getting (on Ubuntu 12.04)

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.10 ...ht,keepaspectratio]{img1.png}
```

What's wrong, what's changed? Alternatives?

**Update**: turns out this only happens with filenames with spaces (so "img 1.pdf", not img1.pdf). How can this be avoided?

Comment: I don't see any reason why this should fail. Is this really the document you tried? Can you show the log-file?

Comment: Your code compiles with any problems.

Comment: Did you add any package by hand, recently?

Comment: It turns out that img1.png works, img 1.png (with a space in the name) doesn't. I guess I've never thought about that before simplifying the test case. But why should the blank matter?

Comment: Do your file names contain the extra space?

Comment: @Chris, yes, see above :)

Comment: Isn't the `grffile` package the normal fix to this? But in general, don;t use spaces in file or folder names.

Comment: Possible Duplicate of [How to include graphics with spaces in their path?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8422/15717). Let us know if the solutions to this Q works to make this Q, a duplicate of high voted Q for better knowledge management ?

Comment: `\usepackage{graphicx} \usepackage[space]{grffile}` solves the spaces-in-filenames issue. I did not realize this was the problem...