# Create parent folder

Tags: external-files

I'm writing my training report. I created different chapters in `multipath`. Now I want to join every chapter in one file.

I use this command

```
\include{C:/Users/ETTIEN/Google Drive/Rapport de stage/chapitre 1/Chapitre1.tex}
```

but it doesn't work. Maybe because of the space in the directory? Or is there any package needed?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to include graphics with spaces in their path?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8422/5764)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Spaces are surely a problem; but the main problem is that LaTeX wants to write an auxiliary file in the directory where `Chapitre1.tex` lives and, for security reasons, it refuses to do so when a full path is given.

Comment: so how can i?? Should i put every file in the same folder

Comment: @user52525 If your main file is in the directory `Rapport de stage`, rename `chapitre 1` into `chapitre1` and use `\include{chapitre1/Chapitre1}` (don't add `.tex`).