# pdflatex.EXE: Not enough room in an internal buffer

Tags: graphics, compiling, external-files

I've got a (hopefully) trivial problem. I have a python script that is generating the a .tex file for over 600 figures. The code automatically groups figures in up to 4 subplots depending on some parameters. I ran a brief test script with a reduced number of figures and everything went fine. Then, when running the entire batch of images I get the error:

> *geometry* driver: auto-detecting
>   *geometry* detected driver: pdftex [1{C:/Users/ln/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}]
>   ("P:...\Appendix_A.lof") [1] [1]pdflatex.EXE:
>   Not enough room in an internal buffer. texify: pdflatex failed for
>   some reason (see log file).

The log file is useless and has the same info. The script gets the error in the code below:

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
\subcapcentertrue
\centering
    \subfigure[Comparison of percentile concentrations at Location ID 13]{%
        \includegraphics[width=0.45\linewidth]{"Biochemical Oxygen Demand 5 Day Un-Diluted_mgL_Percent Saturation Field Dissolved Oxygen_perSAT_13_pp.png"}
        \label{fig:subfigure}}
    \quad
%
\caption{QQ plots comparing Biochemical Oxygen Demand 5 Day Un-Diluted, mg/L, and Percent Saturation Field Dissolved Oxygen, perSAT.}
\label{fig:figure}
\end{figure}
\clearpage
```

If I change the includegraphics line to something shorter, like:

```
\includegraphics[width=0.45\linewidth]{Alkalinity as CaCO3_mgL_pH_pH Units_13_pp.png}
```

Everything runs fine. I'm starting the file path at C:, so this shouldn't be a windows file path length error. Is there a limitation on the length of an image name in LaTeX that I don't know about? I would ideally like to not regenerate the figures using a different naming convention.

Cheers

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: I have seen the error message in combination with spaces in files names (not a good idea) and too long \graphicspath content. But without an example to test it is difficult to find the real cause.

Comment: The issue is directly related to the length of the graphicspath. I resolved the issue by writing into the python script a function to copy and rename the figures to a new location for use the LaTeX. I'm pretty new to LaTeX, is there a place I can submit a bug/issue request?

Answer (score 2):

I resolved the issue by changing the file names of the images so that they are sorter and without spaces. I believe this is a bug.

Comment: I too had a problem with internal buffers, but of different sort (when using large trees with Forest package). Hoping that someone somewhere finally realizes that we are now dealing with gigabytes of RAM available and relaxes the buffer size requirements across the board.

Comment: Agreed. The only time I truly rely on TeX is for very large appendixes with hundreds of images.

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed use file names with whitespaces if you use the package `grffile`, see [How to include graphics with spaces in their path?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8422/how-to-include-graphics-with-spaces-in-their-path).

Answer (score 0):

I had faced this issue before ...

1. ensure the `\graphicspath` is point to the right folders of your image such as

   ```
   \usepackage{graphicx}
   \graphicspath{{../imagesFolder1/},{/imagesFolder2}}
   ```

   the first folder to one level up and the second folder point to the same level of the text file path.
2. remove the the folder name from the path of `\includegraphics`, i.e., 
   `\includegraphics{myFigure1.pdf}` — this is the right way while 
   `\includegraphics{/imagesFolder2/ComputerScienceLogoBlack.pdf}` is causing the error you have currently.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The OP does not even use `\graphicspath`.

Comment: @TeXnician: In a comment he told us, he has: *"The issue is directly related to the length of the graphicspath."* Nevertheless, I don't think, that removing the path from `\includegraphics` reduces the internal buffer consumption. Using `\graphicspath` usually needs more internal memory and time to build and test several file names paths.

Comment: @Schweinebacke Sorry, you're right. I've only seen UlrikeFischer comment on it.

Comment: @Schweinebacke thanks for the reply! I think my comment was me being inattentive - I probably meant to write the length of the file path to the images, not the length of \graphicspath. But that was a few years ago so ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

I saw this issue when I was compiling a latex file in a deep directory tree.  Once I shortened some of the names of the directories in this tree, the problem disappeared.