# Why does \includegraphics ignore the space in a filename?

Tags: graphics

I use the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics{GR0568 q28.png}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

and get this output:

[image: output]

Why does it publish "q28.png"? I'm sure I could fix this if I didn't have a space in the filename, but is there another workaround?

Comment: Do the answers to [How to include graphics with spaces in their path?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8422/how-to-include-graphics-with-spaces-in-their-path) help?

Comment: You can always rename the picture filename for a name for a human,not a robot.

Comment: you see the same with `\input` filenames are not automatically quoted for spaces but if you must you can (with web2c based tex implementations) use `"file foo .png"`