# The path of image causing error at compiling

Tags: graphics, pdftex

I have this path of one of my images:

```
\includegraphics[trim=0cm 0cm 0cm  0cm,clip,scale=.40]{Figures/Simulation_C_044 _023_4_21kV.pdf}
```

When I compile the code, it shows me that there is an error in the line of the path. When I changed the name of the figure with other name, it works fine.

Do you have any idea of solving this problem as I don't prefer to change the file names.

Comment: If the space in the file name is correct, then it's a duplicate: [How to include graphics with spaces in their path?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8422/16967)

Comment: sorry, without space :)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by using :

```
 \usepackage{grffile}
```

Comment: On that basis, a dupe.