# How to take out the File Path above my image

Tags: diagrams, mac

I've tried all the links nothing works. I'm using a mac.
Packages I'm using are:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
```

Keeps coming out with the stupid `Board.png` on top how do I delete?

[image]

```
\begin{figure}[ht!]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=64mm]{Top Board.png}
\caption*{Particles striking 2+ fibers on the top boards \label{overflow}}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Using your code with pdflatex don't show any trouble with article as document class.

Comment: Did you see [How to include graphics with spaces in their path?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8422) as well? Adding `\usepackage{grffile}` fixes it for me. (Or just don't use spaces in filenames...)