# Lyx, referencing and classic thesis

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, lyx, biber, classicthesis

I have some issues with referencing in LyX and the classicthesis template. Ive built my .bib file with Mendeley. 
Referencing with the example bibliography works properly, however, when I load my own .bib file, it stops working. Citationkeys are shown instead of the proper reference.
[image: Illustration of citationkey]

Ive used the pre-created bibliography button to load my .bib file in the classicthesis.lyx file, and also edited the preamble so that it loads my bib file.
 I also made sure the .bib file is in the same folder as all the .lyx files.

```
    \addbibresource{filename.bib}
```

Otherwise I haven't edited any settings. I have looked at other questions asked here at Stackexchange, but none specifically address this issue. Could anyone give me guidance in how to fix this?

Edit:
Trying PhilipPirrip's suggestion, I still get the same result. I've copied the Bibtex log here:

This is 8-bit Big BibTeX version 0.99d
Implementation:  C for Unix
Release version: 3.71 (18 mar 2013)

The 8-bit codepage and sorting file: 88591lat.csf
The top-level auxiliary file: bibliography-biblatex-bibtex8.aux
The style file: biblatex.bst
White space in argument---line 20 of file bibliography-biblatex-bibtex8.aux
 : \bibdata{bibliography-biblatex-bibtex8-blx,/Users/name/Downloads/Bibliography-BibLaTeX//file
 :                                                                                                           name}
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
Reallocated glb_str_ptr (elt_size=8) to 10 items from 0.

Reallocated global_strs (elt_size=20001) to 10 items from 0.

Reallocated glb_str_end (elt_size=8) to 10 items from 0.

Reallocated singl_function (elt_size=8) to 100 items from 50.

Reallocated singl_function (elt_size=8) to 100 items from 50.

Reallocated singl_function (elt_size=8) to 100 items from 50.

Reallocated singl_function (elt_size=8) to 100 items from 50.

Reallocated singl_function (elt_size=8) to 100 items from 50.

Reallocated wiz_functions (elt_size=8) to 6000 items from 3000.

Reallocated singl_function (elt_size=8) to 100 items from 50.

Reallocated singl_function (elt_size=8) to 100 items from 50.

Reallocated singl_function (elt_size=8) to 100 items from 50.

Reallocated singl_function (elt_size=8) to 100 items from 50.

Reallocated singl_function (elt_size=8) to 100 items from 50.

Database file #1: bibliography-biblatex-bibtex8-blx.bib

Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "Newton1686"

Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "Aaron2001"

Biblatex version: 3.0

Reallocated singl_function (elt_size=8) to 100 items from 50.

Reallocated wiz_functions (elt_size=8) to 9000 items from 6000.

Here's how much of BibTeX's memory you used:
 Cites:                 1 out of 750
 Fields:               11 out of 5000
 Hash table:        34716 out of 35307
 Strings:            1130 out of 35307
 Free string pool:   8165 out of 65000
 Wizard functions:   6047 out of 9000
(There was 1 error message)

Comment: Anything suspicious in Document>LaTeX log>Log Type BibTeX? Try adding your bib file to one of these http://wiki.lyx.org/uploads/BibTeX/Bibliography-BibLaTeX.zip

Comment: Normally, with LyX you have to give the full path to the `.bib` file (unless it resides in your local texmf tree). I think your template applies some of the tricks from the LyX wiki to get around that, but I don't know how robust those tricks are, so they might brake with weird file names.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved this issue by examining other questsions posted on stackexchange, and randomly trying "solutions". The problem is somehow related with the length filename. I had a filename with 13 characters, and now that I've changed it to three characters, it somehow works.

Comment: Is it related to the length of filename, or the characters used in filename? (I.e. did the first name of your `.bib` file contained special characters that could have caused an error in processing?

Comment: Originally, it contained a space. I haven't tested whether that caused the problem, but it certainly might've.

Comment: So this might be related: [How to include graphics with spaces in their path?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8422/how-to-include-graphics-with-spaces-in-their-path)