# one folder for graphics using graphicspath

Tags: graphics, paths

I am using `graphicspath` in order to pick up pictures from a unique folder for my beamer presentation.

My code is:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=pdftex,t,11pt]{beamer}


\usepackage{graphicx}

\graphicspath{{C:/Users/my name/Dropbox (Personale)/Public/Note Lezioni/images/}}


\begin{document}


\begin{frame}
\frametitle{My graphs}
\framesubtitle{This is the slide with graphs}
\begin{itemize}
\item Consider the following:
\end{itemize}\bigskip
\pause[2]
\begin {figure}
\begin{minipage}{0.6\textheight}
\includegraphics[width=5.5 cm,height=3 cm]{rgdpna}
\caption{fig1}
\end{minipage}
\pause[3]
\begin{minipage}{0.6\textheight}
\includegraphics[width=5.5 cm,height=3 cm]{pc}
\caption{fig2}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I cannot understand which is my mistake, but when I compile the file, I get the error message that file rgdpna is not found? Any suggestion?

Comment: Might be related to [How to include graphics with spaces in their path?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8422/100384)?

Comment: @Timm. Thanks for your reply. Apparently, I should write \graphicspath{{C:\Users\dario\Dropbox (Personale)\Public\Note Lezioni}} instead of \graphicspath{{C:/Users/my name/Dropbox (Personale)/Public/Note Lezioni/images/}} and then I recall the folder with the pics in includegraphics, i.e. \includegraphics[width=5.5 cm,height=3 cm]{images/rgdpna}

Comment: no never use `\ ` always `/` but where is the main document? if it is also in dropbox can you not just specify `{images}` as the graphics path? it's always best to avoid full paths as the make the document non portable

Comment: unrelated but do not specify both height and width to `\includegraphics` or the image will be distorted.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle. Thanks David. I know that is better not use \ but /. However, when I use /, the picture is not found and I am wondering way. I have on Dropbox a folder with some lecture notes. Inside I have 4 sub-folders, one for each different module. I included a fifth sub-folder (images) into the main one. Also thanks about the second suggestion.

Comment: if you use `\Dropbox` then latex will just report `\Dropbox` as an undefined command and it won't work at all.