# Graphics not centering

Tags: graphics, floats, horizontal-alignment

I am trying to center graphics in TexShop. This is the code that I am using but the graphics are not getting centering whatever I try to do.

```
 \begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height = 2.3in]{/Users/LOCATION/Matrix1.png}   
    \caption{Generated Matrix}
\end{figure}
```

The code is giving me this image

[image: Error Image]

I tried using

```
\begin{center}
...
end{center}
```

instead of `\centering` but nothing seems to be fixing the problem.

EDIT 1 : Full Code

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
 \begin{figure}[H]
     \centering
    \caption{Generated Matrix}  
    \includegraphics[height = 2.3in] {/Users/Max/Desktop/Math IA/PhysicsDrawings/Matrix1.png}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Try `\fbox{\includegraphics ... }`. Do you get a lot of white space around the image? Also (unrelated to the problem): png isn't a good format for an image that contains text. `eps` or `pdf` would be better.

Comment: @campa The 'IA/PhysicsDrawings/Matrix1.png' is not part of the image

Comment: Is `LOCATION` a path that includes spaces?

Comment: Texshop is only the editor. The question should be completely independent from the editor but [not independent from the image file and it's real name in a MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: hard to tell as you have not shown the code that produced output that you show, but it looks like your path has a space in it, but isn't being used so `\includegraphics[height = 2.3in]{Matrix1.png} ` should worrk.

Comment: @IanThompson I tried using `\fbox` but that didn't seem to help. Here is more of the code including the actual location of the file...   `\begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
  \caption{Generated Matrix} 
  \includegraphics[height = 2.3in] {/Users/Max/Desktop/Math IA/PhysicsDrawings/Matrix1.png}
\end{figure}`

Is there any problems with this?

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem. You can replace the actual file with `example-image`.

Comment: When you used `\fbox`, did you see white space between the image and the frame or not?

Comment: @erik Thanks for adding that I edited the question to show more of the code

Comment: I suggest you take a look at the question [How to include graphics with spaces in their path?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8422/24974)

Comment: @IanThompson Yeah, there was a lot of white space between the frame and the image

Comment: @erik Thanks for the comment! That completely fixed the formatting... Didn't realise that spaces in the title would cause a problem with my image.